# How to write maths symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I  have written in my work `$X^{+},\,\rm{e}^{X},\,|X|^{p}$`. Why is the second and third term not in italics?

Comment: Because you used `\rm` instead of `\mathrm`.

Comment: The command `\rm` is a *switch*, i.e., all subsequent material (until either the math environment ends or a different font-related switch is encountered) is affected by the command. To limit its scope, you should type `{\rm e}` instead of `\rm{e}`. Much better, though: Use `\mathrm{e}`. The command `\rm` is a holdover from "Plain TeX" and is not supported fully in LaTeX!

Comment: JLDiaz/@Mico: Please compose an answer so this can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you used `\rm` instead of `\mathrm`.

`\rm` is not a macro which accepts an argument, as you apparently thought. The macro which does that is `\textrm{text}` for text mode and `\mathrm{text}` for math mode. Instead, macro `\rm` changes the current font to roman, from the point in which the macro appears *until the end of the current scope* (which is the end of the math mode in your case, but more generally the end of the group in which `\rm` appears).

Macros `\it`, `\bf` and `\tt`, work in the same line than `\rm`, and they have also a version which accepts one parameter, which are `\textit{}` (but more frequently `\emph{}`), `\textbf{}` and `\textt{}`.

Those two-letter macros which change fonts and styles are deprecated and should not be used. They are maintained for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Also see/mention/reference [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Answer (score 2):

Summing up what JLDiaz and Mico have said in the comments:

The correct thing to use here is `\mathrm`. So you should have:

```
$X^{+},\,\mathrm{e}^{X},\,|X|^{p}$
```

`\rm` is a font selection macro from `Plain TeX` and does a toggle, so that all subsequent material in the current scope will be affected. It would be possible to do `{\rm e}`, but actually `\rm` is deprecated in current `LaTeX`.

If you need something similar for text-mode you can use `\textrm{some text}` there.

In the case that you want to define math symbols similar to `\sin` you can use e.g. `\DeclareMathOperator{\gr}{gr}` from `amsmath` package, which adjusts the font too, but also takes care of spacing. You use it as `\gr`.

Comment: Oops... We collided, I was redacting my answer at the same time than you. Sorry

Comment: @JLDiaz: what is normally done in such cases?

Comment: No idea... I guess we can leave both answers until a moderator gives us advice.