# How to boldface a section header? (including title and number)

Tags: sectioning, bold, amsart

I'm using class `amsart`, and I want to boldface each section's header.

That is, the part `\section{whatever}` - it appears as, for instance, <3. **Whatever**>

Now I wish to boldface the **<3. Whatever>** as a whole.

Writing as `\section{\bf whatever}`, or inserting

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\section}{\scshape}{\bf}{}{}
\makeatother
```

solve the problem partly by boldfacing the `< Whatever>` part, but not the `<3.>` part. Can somebody please tell me how to boldface the whole thing?

Comment: Regarding the use of `\bf`, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Answer (score 9):

The instruction for the font used for the number is called `\@secnumfont`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@secnumfont}{\bfseries}
\makeatother
```

So the complete input should be

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\section}{\scshape}{\bfseries}{}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@secnumfont}{\bfseries}
\makeatother
```

<sub>*Never* use the obsolete commands `\bf` (or similar two-letter ones for font changing).</sub>

Comment: For those who want to keeps small caps while adding boldface: Use the package "fontenc", then include egreg's input above, but replace the two instances of "{\bfseries}" with "{\scshape\bfseries}".