# How to boldface only a subsection number in amsart?

Tags: sectioning, bold, amsart

If I use the code

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@secnumfont}{\bfseries}
\makeatother
```

from [How to boldface a section header? (including title and number)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64922/how-to-boldface-a-section-header-including-title-and-number) it makes the number of sections bold as well. How to get a boldface number only for subsection? Looking into amsart.cls, it seems like there is not a specific command for sub(sub)sections or paragraphs.

Comment: do you want the heading of the subsection bold, or just the number?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Both, but subsection is already bold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tapping into `\@seccntformat` you can format the section counter display to suit your needs based on the type of counter that is being used.

Below I've added a conditional that checks whether you're setting the `subsection` counter. If so, use `\bfseries`. Of course, this can be expanded to change other sectional counter setting as well by adding more conditions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \protect\textup{\protect\@secnumfont
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{subsection}{#1}=0 \bfseries\fi% subsection # in \bfseries
    \csname the#1\endcsname
    \protect\@secnumpunct
  }%
}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

This requires e-TeX due to `\pdfstrcmp`.

Comment: Splendid, I again learned something new...

Answer (score 4):

Werner's idea of tapping into `\@seccntformat` is good, but there's a slicker way to do it: add a command of the form `\format<level>`; if the command is not defined, being used with `\csname...\endcsname` will make it equivalent to `\relax`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \protect\textup{%
    \protect\@secnumfont
    \expandafter\protect\csname format#1\endcsname % <--- added
    \csname the#1\endcsname
    \protect\@secnumpunct
  }%
}

% define what you want for the various levels
\newcommand{\formatsubsection}{\bfseries}
%\newcommand{\formatsubsubsection}{\Huge} %%%% try for experimenting

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Try, just by way of experimenting, to uncomment the `\formatsubsubsection` line.

Comment: Slick indeed, as undefined `\format<level>` macros are just "ignored".

Answer (score 0):

Amsart has a curious behavior: if a subsection title is empty, its number is bold.  This is achieved by the following lines inside `\sect` definition:

```
\@ifempty{#8}{%
  \ifnum #2=\tw@ \def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}\fi}{}%
```

Here `#2` is the section level (1 for section, 2 for subsection, 3 for subsubsection etc).

So what you need is to take out the check whether title (`#8`) is empty, and subsection number will be always bold.

This does the trick (I just took the amsart code and deleted `\@ifempty` check):

```
\makeatletter
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \edef\@toclevel{\ifnum#2=\@m 0\else\number#2\fi}%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \else \@xp\let\@xp\@secnumber\csname the#1\endcsname\fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef\@secnumpunct{%
      \ifdim\@tempskipa>\z@ % not a run-in section heading
        \@ifnotempty{#8}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \else
        \@ifempty{#8}{.}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \fi
    }%
    \ifnum #2=\tw@ \def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}\fi
    \protected@edef\@svsec{%
      \ifnum#2<\@m
        \@ifundefined{#1name}{}{%
          \ignorespaces\csname #1name\endcsname\space
        }%
      \fi
      \@seccntformat{#1}%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@ % then this is not a run-in section heading
    \begingroup #6\relax
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}{\interlinepenalty\@M #8\par}%
    \endgroup
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  \else
  \def\@svsechd{#6\hskip #3\@svsec
    \@ifnotempty{#8}{\ignorespaces#8\unskip
       \@addpunct.}%
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  }%
  \fi
  \global\@nobreaktrue
  \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This will also format the `\subsubsection` counter in `\bfseries`.