# How to put the footnote texts on the footnote when wrap text with a box

Tags: footnotes, boxes

I tried the following code but the footnote text is wrapped into the box. Anyway to put the footnote texts on the footnote of the page?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\definecolor{light}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,1}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.27,0.4,0.87}


\newmdenv[innerlinewidth=0.5pt,
roundcorner=3pt,linecolor=darkblue,backgroundcolor=light, shadow=true]{soa}

\begin{document}

\begin{soa}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 1~\footnote{footnote text 1}
\end{soa}

\begin{soa}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 2~\footnote{footnote text 2}
\end{soa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: The round cornered box solution comes from this post: [How to construct a coloured box with rounded corners](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66154/how-to-construct-a-coloured-box-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: According to the manual, `mdframed` uses a minipage, so the footnotes are inside the `mdframed` box

Comment: Any chance to work around this? :(

Comment: I don't know how to get footnotes out of a minipage environment.

Comment: i think the solution will be to use `\footnotmark` inside the box and `\footnotetext` just after the box.  there may be side effects, and there are definitely complications if more than one footnote is inside the same box; i haven't tested it.

Comment: `footnote` package with its `savenotes` and `spewnotes` works to some extent. Only draw back is foot notes inside `minipage` have their own counter that resets after the mini page.