# customizing the algorithmic package: break and  loop labels

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I would like to add two customizations to the algorithmic package: introduce a new break command and have the possibility to provide labels to the LOOP so that `break {label}` is clear to which loop is referring to. I tried to introduce the break command like this:

```
\newcommand{\algorithmicbreak}{\textbf{break}}
```

but this won't work, I get the unknown command error when I type `\BREAK`

However, with this hack I can make it work but it is very unnice:

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmicprint}{\textbf{break}}
% then use it as 
\PRINT
```

The LOOP labels I have no idea how to introduce.

UPDATE: my full example

```
    \begin{algorithm}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicprint}{\textbf{break}}
    \caption{\text{My-Algorithm}}
    \label{algo:blah}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \REQUIRE X
    \ENSURE Y
    % STEP 1
    \STATE \COMMENT{{\bf Step 1}} some something
    \LOOP % can't annotate the loop :(((
        % STEP 2
        \STATE \COMMENT{{\bf Step 2}} do something more
        \IF {$a = b$}
            \RETURN $c$
        \ELSE
            \LOOP % can't annotate the loop :(((
                % STEP 3
                \STATE \COMMENT{{\bf Step 3}} do some more
                \IF {$b = c$}
                    \STATE $y = x$
                    \PRINT % intending to break
                \ELSE
                    % STEP 4
                    \STATE \COMMENT{{\bf Step 4}} and yet some more
                \ENDIF
            \ENDLOOP
        \ENDIF
    \ENDLOOP
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question a simple document with an algorithm showing in what cases you want the break to appear? You question is a little confusing for me (you mention the `algorithmic` package, tag with "algorithmicx", and it's not clear to what "LOOP" you are referring to).

Comment: Someone edited my tags, that's why ... when people go trigger happy editing other people's questions this is what happens => lot of confusion :)

Comment: Ah, I see now. Once you add the little example, I'll retag if that's OK with you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a modification added to [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) that allows you to `\BREAK` and have an annotated loop `\ALOOP` (and `\ENDALOOP`). It is based on a copy of the regular `\LOOP` and `\ENDLOOP` combinations, with an added parameter for annotation. Of course, more modifications are possible:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms

% Algorithmic modifications
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ALOOP}[1]{\ALC@it\algorithmicloop\ #1%
  \begin{ALC@loop}}
\newcommand{\ENDALOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}\ALC@it\algorithmicendloop}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicbreak}{\textbf{break}}
\newcommand{\BREAK}{\STATE \algorithmicbreak}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My-Algorithm}\label{algo:blah}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \show\LOOP
    \REQUIRE X
    \ENSURE Y
    % STEP 1
    \STATE \COMMENT{\textbf{Step 1}} some something
    \ALOOP {outer} % Outer loop
        % STEP 2
        \STATE \COMMENT{\textbf{Step 2}} do something more
        \IF {$a = b$}
            \RETURN $c$
        \ELSE
            \ALOOP {inner} % Inner loop
                % STEP 3
                \STATE \COMMENT{\textbf{Step 3}} do some more
                \IF {$b = c$}
                    \STATE $y = x$
                    \BREAK % intending to break
                \ELSE
                    % STEP 4
                    \STATE \COMMENT{\textbf{Step 4}} and yet some more
                \ENDIF
            \ENDALOOP
        \ENDIF
    \ENDALOOP
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}​
```

It would also be possible to modify `\BREAK` to take an argument if you want to annotate that as well (like breaking out of a specific loop, say).

For completeness, I've fixed your use of `\bf`. As such, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Answer (score 11):

This is all much easier if you use the [algoritmicx package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx), it has a lot more functionality and works better with other packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=1.25in, bmargin=1.25in, lmargin=1.25in, rmargin=1.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\newcommand{\Break}{\State \textbf{break} }
\algblockdefx[Loop]{Loop}{EndLoop}[1][]{\textbf{Loop} #1}{\textbf{End Loop}}
\begin{document}

Here is an example:

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require Integers $a >0$ and $b$
\Ensure $a\cdot b$
\State $i\leftarrow 0$
\State $c \leftarrow 0$
\Loop{1}
    \If{$i=a$}
        \Break Loop 1
    \EndIf
    \State $c \leftarrow c + b$
    \State $i \leftarrow i + 1$
\EndLoop
\State \textbf{return} $c$
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't accept the answer because I would prefer not having to rewrite my algorithm using yet another package, I am maybe too conservative or lazy :) but thank you!

Comment: @GiovanniAzua I made a similar decision a while ago, but then algorithmic is not compatible with cleveref and is not as flexible, so I eventually swapped. Rewriting is not necessary, you can just do a global search and replace for \STATE to \State, \REQUIRE to \Require etc.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua When you accept answers or not, please consider what will be most helpful for the thousands of other visitors to the discussion and how much time they will waste by being misled reading a suboptimal solution, instead of occasional inconvenience for your particular case. It is not mandatory to use a particular solution for your case in order to accept it. As long as you are confident it works (e.g., by trying the minimal example provided above), you can accept it if you think it is a better solution.