# How would you go about typesetting something like this on TeXworks?

Tags: typography

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz2Zf.png) is one of examples the that appears in the TeXbook (pg. 411) and I tried my hands at typseting it but couldn't. I'm a newbie and was hoping someone here could help, please?

The code supposedly is:

```
\input concert
\tsaologo
\medskip
\centerline{Friday, November 19, 1982, 8:00 p.m.}
\bigskip
\centerline{\bf PROGRAM}
\medskip
\composition{Variations on a Theme by Tchaikovsky}
\composer{Anton S. Arensky (1861--1906)}
\smallskip
{\medtype
\movements{Tema: Moderato\cr
Var.~I: Un poco pi\`u mosso&Var.~V: Andante\cr
Var.~II: Allegro non troppo&Var.~VI: Allegro con spirito\cr
Var.~III: Andantino tranquillo&Var.~VII: Andante con moto\cr
Var.~IV: Vivace&Coda: Moderato\cr}
}
\bigskip
\composition{Concerto for Horn and Hardart, S.\,27}
\composer{P. D. Q. Bach (1807--1742)?}
\smallskip
\movements{Allegro con brillo\cr
Tema con variazione \(su un tema differente)\cr
Menuetto con panna e zucchero\cr}
\medskip
\soloists{Ben Lee User, horn\cr
Peter Schickele, hardart\cr}
\bigskip
\centerline{INTERMISSION}
\bigskip
\composition{Symphony No.\,3 in E\flat\ Major\cr
Op.\,55, ``The Eroica''\cr}
\composer{Ludwig van Beethoven (1770--1827)}
\smallskip
\movements{Allegro con brio\cr
Marcia funebre: Adagio assai\cr
Scherzo: Allegro vivace\cr
Finale: Allegro molto\cr}
\bigskip
\smalltype \noindent
Members of the audience are kindly requested to turn off the
alarms on their digital watches, and to cough only between movements.
\bye
```

Before entering the code (b/w the `\begin` and `\end`), this is what I type:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\headheight -0.5in
\textheight 9.5in
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Also, these macros (or definition - I don't know if they're the same thing) are to be used too:

```
\def\composition#1{\halign{\bf\quad##\hfil\cr
\kern-1em#1\crcr}} % use \cr's if more than one line
\def\composer#1{\rightline{\bf#1}}
\def\movements#1{\halign{\quad\it##\hfil&&\qquad\it##\hfil\cr#1\crcr}}
\def\soloists#1{\centerline{\bf\vbox{\halign{##\hfil\cr#1\crcr}}}}
```

And

```
\def\tsaologo{\vbox{\bigtype\bf
\line{\hrulefill}
\kern-.5\baselineskip
\line{\hrulefill\phantom{ THE ST.\,ANFORD ORCHESTRA }\hrulefill}
\kern-.5\baselineskip
\line{\hrulefill\hbox{ THE ST.\,ANFORD ORCHESTRA }\hrulefill}
\kern-.5\baselineskip
\line{\hrulefill\phantom{ R. J. Drofnats, Conductor }\hrulefill}
\kern-.5\baselineskip
\line{\hrulefill\hbox{ R. J. Drofnats, Conductor }\hrulefill}
}}
```

---

I've noticed that I can use some of the definitions. For example, I get an error when I try using `\tsaologo` but `\composition{Variations on a Theme by Tchaikovsky}` works fine. Also, `\centerline` command doesn't work, but just `\center`

Comment: The TeXbook is a book about *plain* TeX. I am not able to rightly comprehend the confusion of ideas that would cause one to think that something intended for plain TeX --- and depending on an external file that doesn't even exist (i.e. "concert.tex") would work unmodified with LaTeX.

Comment: @kahen Like I said in my post; completely new at this. I just downloaded the program and started reading the book -- from the end. Some of the things worked so I thought I was on the right path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As other have commented, the TeXbook talks about the TeX primitives *and* also of a possible way to use them at a higher level via a macro package called **Plain TeX**, which is quite different from LaTeX.

Reading the TeXbook is useful if you want to be more proficient in LaTeX programming. For document creation in LaTeX a good starting point is the ["Not so short introduction to LaTeX"](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lshort-english/lshort.pdf) which is available in several languages; go to http://texdoc.net and type `lshort` in the box.

A less hybrid LaTeX form of the same can be as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt

\newcommand{\composition}[1]{%
  \par
  {\bfseries
   \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{1em}}l@{}}
   \hspace*{-1em}#1%
   \end{tabular}%
  }%
  \par
} % use \\ if more than one line
\newcommand{\composer}[1]{\par\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\bfseries#1}\par}
%\def\composer#1{\rightline{\bfseries#1}}
\newcommand{\movements}[1]{%
  \par
  \begin{tabular}{@{\quad}>{\itshape}l@{\qquad}>{\itshape}l@{}}
  #1
  \end{tabular}
  \par
}
\newcommand{\soloists}[1]{%
  \par
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
  \par
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\textflat}{%
  {\if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\boldmath\fi$\flat$}%
}
\makeatother

\def\tsaologo{\vbox{\Large\bfseries
\hbox to \hsize{\hrulefill}
\kern-.5\baselineskip
\hbox to \hsize{\hrulefill\phantom{ THE ST.\,ANFORD ORCHESTRA }\hrulefill}
\kern-.5\baselineskip
\hbox to \hsize{\hrulefill\hbox{ THE ST.\,ANFORD ORCHESTRA }\hrulefill}
\kern-.5\baselineskip
\hbox to \hsize{\hrulefill\phantom{ R. J. Drofnats, Conductor }\hrulefill}
\kern-.5\baselineskip
\hbox to \hsize{\hrulefill\hbox{ R. J. Drofnats, Conductor }\hrulefill}
}}
\begin{document}

\tsaologo

\medskip

\centerline{Friday, November 19, 1982, 8:00 p.m.}

\bigskip

\centerline{\bfseries PROGRAM}

\medskip

\composition{Variations on a Theme by Tchaikovsky}
\composer{Anton S. Arensky (1861--1906)}
\smallskip
{\small
\movements{Tema: Moderato\\
Var.~I: Un poco pi\`u mosso    & Var.~V: Andante\\
Var.~II: Allegro non troppo    & Var.~VI: Allegro con spirito\\
Var.~III: Andantino tranquillo & Var.~VII: Andante con moto\\
Var.~IV: Vivace&Coda: Moderato}
}

\bigskip

\composition{Concerto for Horn and Hardart, S.\,27}
\composer{P. D. Q. Bach (1807--1742)?}
\smallskip
\movements{Allegro con brillo\\
Tema con variazione \textup{(}su un tema differente\textup{)}\\
Menuetto con panna e zucchero\\}
\medskip
\soloists{Ben Lee User, horn\\
Peter Schickele, hardart}

\bigskip
\centerline{INTERMISSION}
\bigskip

\composition{Symphony No.\,3 in E\textflat\ Major\\
Op.\,55, ``The Eroica''\\}
\composer{Ludwig van Beethoven (1770--1827)}
\smallskip
\movements{Allegro con brio\\
Marcia funebre: Adagio assai\\
Scherzo: Allegro vivace\\
Finale: Allegro molto\\}

\vfill

\footnotesize
Members of the audience are kindly requested to turn off the
alarms on their digital watches, and to cough only between movements.

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Only the `\tsaologo` macro has been retained, it's quite hard to produce it with pure LaTeX commands. Of course one could benefit from TikZ for this.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for your problems might be that the original code was written for TeX, not LaTeX. Here's a hybrid solution (still containing most of the TeX code) that works:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\def\tsaologo{\vbox{\large\bfseries
  \noindent\hrulefill\par
  \kern-.5\baselineskip
  \noindent\hrulefill\phantom{ THE ST.\,ANFORD ORCHESTRA }\hrulefill\par
  \kern-.5\baselineskip
  \noindent\hrulefill\hbox{ THE ST.\,ANFORD ORCHESTRA }\hrulefill\par
  \kern-.5\baselineskip
  \noindent\hrulefill\phantom{ R.\ J.\ Drofnats, Conductor }\hrulefill\par
  \kern-.5\baselineskip
  \noindent\hrulefill\hbox{ R.\ J.\ Drofnats, Conductor }\hrulefill
}}

\def\composition#1{\halign{\bfseries\quad##\hfil\cr
\kern-1em#1\crcr}} % use \cr's if more than one line
\def\composer#1{\rightline{\bfseries#1}}
\def\movements#1{\halign{\quad\itshape##\hfil&&\qquad\itshape##\hfil\cr#1\crcr}}
\def\soloists#1{\centerline{\bfseries\vbox{\halign{##\hfil\cr#1\crcr}}}}

\begin{document}

%\input concert% Definitions given in preamble
\tsaologo
\medskip
\centerline{Friday, November 19, 1982, 8:00 p.m.}
\bigskip
\centerline{\bfseries PROGRAM}
\medskip
\composition{Variations on a Theme by Tchaikovsky}
\composer{Anton S. Arensky (1861--1906)}
\smallskip
{\normalsize
  \movements{Tema: Moderato\cr
    Var.~I: Un poco pi\`u mosso&Var.~V: Andante\cr
    Var.~II: Allegro non troppo&Var.~VI: Allegro con spirito\cr
    Var.~III: Andantino tranquillo&Var.~VII: Andante con moto\cr
    Var.~IV: Vivace&Coda: Moderato\cr}
}
\bigskip
\composition{Concerto for Horn and Hardart, S.\,27}
\composer{P. D. Q. Bach (1807--1742)?}
\smallskip
\movements{Allegro con brillo\cr
  Tema con variazione $($su un tema differente$)$\cr
  Menuetto con panna e zucchero\cr}
\medskip
\soloists{Ben Lee User, horn\cr
  Peter Schickele, hardart\cr}
\bigskip
\centerline{INTERMISSION}
\bigskip
\composition{Symphony No.\,3 in E$\flat$\ Major\cr
  Op.\,55, ``The Eroica''\cr}
\composer{Ludwig van Beethoven (1770--1827)}
\smallskip
\movements{Allegro con brio\cr
  Marcia funebre: Adagio assai\cr
  Scherzo: Allegro vivace\cr
  Finale: Allegro molto\cr}
\bigskip
\small \noindent
Members of the audience are kindly requested to turn off the
alarms on their digital watches, and to cough only between movements.

\end{document}
```

Most changes were in terms of font selection. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and/or [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)