# How can I get TeXstudio's syntax highlighting to recognize an unknown command?

Tags: texstudio

TeXstudio does not recognize the LaTeX command `\rm` (red highlighting in the document, with the message: `unrecognized command`), even after I activate all possible completion files (`.cwl`).

In such a case, what can I do so that TeXstudio recognizes a certain command for highlighting?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  I don't think `\rm` is a standard macro -- at least I never heard if it.

Comment: `\rm` has been declared obsolete some years ago and it's best *not* to use it, just like the companion commands `\it`, `\bf`, `\sf` and `\tt`.

Comment: Please throw away your obsolete LaTeX documentation that suggested `\rm` (it has been deprecated since 1993) and get one more actually describing LaTeX2e.

Comment: With the general wording of the question as it is now, I don't think there's any reason to close it as _too localized_. (Didn't really think there was one before that either.)

Answer (score 12):

This is still a recognized command (for legacy purposes), but should be avoided. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764).

TeXstudio does allow you to add commands that are not recognized to its list of known control sequences. Under *Options* -> *Configure TeXstudio...* check *Show Advanced Options* and add `\rm` to the list of *Additional Commands* as part of your *Custom Highlighting*:

[image]

Your document syntax highlight should change from

[image]

to

[image]

Another approach (perhaps better for legacy documents) is to replace any two-letter font style commands with their updated counterparts:

```
\renewcommand{\rm}{\rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\it}{\itshape}
%...
```

This renewal will also be picked up by TeXstudio.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to modify legacy documents in that way: `\rm\it` was *different* from `\it\rm` in LaTeX2.09 and still is with the two letter commands. The best is forgetting them altogether.

Comment: In TeXstudio 2.6.6 (Windows) on my computer, this fix only works after restarting TeXstudio.