# My symbols are rendered as ff. Have I ran out of memory?

Tags: symbols, errors

I have been trying to solve a 4x4 matrix and have done a hell a lot of writing. Now I am near the end and I am not getting the requested output out of the LaTeX compiler.

When I write for example:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\begin{equation}\label{e50}
R^{-1} = \frac{1}{\left|R\right|} \rm{adj}(R) = \alpha
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
```

the last symbol isn't shown as "alpha" but rather as a very weird symbol `ff` like I show in the picture below:

[image]

I get the same weird symbol for any symbol that I put in place of `\alpha` or even after it. From this point on all of my symbols are typeset as `ff`.

If I put same source code in my other new document all of my symbols again render as they were supposed to.

**Q1:** Have I ran out of memory?

**Q2:** How can I fix this?

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764) regarding the use of old font macros.

Answer (score 12):

You shouldn't be getting `ff` instead of `\alpha`. But your input has a bad error anyway: `\rm` is *not* a command with an argument, but rather a *declaration* that extends its influence until the group in which it's been issued ends, in this case up to `\end{equation}`.

The command `\rm` *must not* be used. Forget it, together with `\it`, `\bf` and `\tt`. They are obsolete and, as in your case, can be misunderstood by users.

In place of them use `\textrm`, `\textit`, `\texttt` and the others that you find in any user guide. In math there are `\mathrm` and some similar commands, but for operator names there's a better way: say

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj}
```

in your preamble and then your formula can be input as

```
\begin{equation}\label{e50}
R^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lvert R\rvert} \adj(R) = \alpha
\end{equation}
```

The `minipage` you use is not needed and probably makes vertical spacing awkward. Note also `\lvert` and `\rvert` instead of `\left|` and `\right|.

Comment: Ty your anwser solved my problem. Why is command `\rm` even there if i cannot use it? It didn't ruin my other equations...

Comment: @71GA The command is still needed for backward compatibility, as older document may have it. *Never* use it yourself.

Comment: @71GA -- egreg is right; you shouldn't use the old 2-letter font commands.  but if you *must* use it, then use it as `{/rm ...}`.  this is what egreg meant when he said your input had an error.