# Preventing newline from left column from forcing a newline in the right column

Tags: tables, line-breaking, vertical-alignment, resume

I'm writing a CV in LaTeX, and got started with the sample called [Writing a CV in LaTeX](http://texblog.org/2012/04/25/writing-a-cv-in-latex/).

I'm trying to modify it so that a newline in the left column does not force a newline in the right column. Here's what I've got so far:

preamble:

```
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}
```

columns:

```
\section*{Professional Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
June 2012 -- present&{\bf Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries}\\
&\lipsum[66]\vspace{5pt}\\
Sept. 2011 -- Apr. 2012&{\bf Intern Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries}\\
&\lipsum[66]\\
\end{tabular}
```

Here's the output: [image: output]

I added arrows to indicate the right-column linebreaks that I'd like to eliminate. Any pointers for this would be great.

Comment: The two answers provided so far are excellent and it's ridiculous that I can choose only one as correct.

Comment: Yeah, you won't use both solutions, so you shall tick the one you'll use. And just one suggestion: I believe that saying `June~2012 to~present` and `Sep.~2011 to~Apr.~2012` would look better (the dates would be all nicely aligned to each other). At least you should do `Sep.\@ 2011` to prevent inter-sentence space to be included.

Comment: Sounds good. Great community!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about some nestedness (that *must* be a neologism in this context) of `tabular`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor,array}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.25pt}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{\dimexpr0.8\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.25pt}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{Professional Experience}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
  June 2012 -- present & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}R@{}}
    \textbf{Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries} \\
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{tabular} \\[\bigskipamount]
  Sept. 2011 -- Apr. 2012 & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}R@{}}
    \textbf{Intern Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries} \\
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Some modifications to your code include:

- Using the font changing macro `\textbf` rather than `\bf` (an old school switch). See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf` , `\it` , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764);
- `[t]`op-aligning the right `tabular` with the left column entry;
- Making the width of the `tabular` fit *exactly* within the page boundary by removing the appropriate amount of space from the desired column widths;
- Removing the inter-column space by using a column specifier `@{}`.

Answer (score 7):

The [`multirow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) package can help you here.

If you rather want to set manual line-breaks, you can just explicitly divide the text across the first column, i.e.

```
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
    June 2012 --  & {\bf Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries}        \\
    present       & \lipsum[66]\vspace{5pt}                          \\
    Sept. 2011 -- & {\bf Intern Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries} \\
    Apr. 2012     & \lipsum*[66]                                     \\
\end{tabular}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,array,lipsum,multirow}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}
\begin{document}
\section*{Professional Experience (Orig)}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
    June 2012 -- present    & {\bf Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries}        \\
                            & \lipsum[66]\vspace{5pt}                          \\
    Sept. 2011 -- Apr. 2012 & {\bf Intern Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries} \\
                            & \lipsum[66]                                      \\
\end{tabular}
\section*{Professional Experience (multirow)}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\raggedleft June~2012 -- present}    & {\bfseries Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries}        \\
                                                                  & \lipsum[66]\vspace{5pt}                                \\
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\raggedleft Sept.~2011 -- Apr.~2012} & {\bfseries Intern Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries} \\
                                                                  & \lipsum*[66]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 6):

No `\multirow` nor nested `tabular` environments:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor,array,lipsum,collcell}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\MyDates}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcommand{\MyDates}[1]{\parbox[t][0pt]{.14\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}

\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}
\begin{document}
\section*{Professional Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
June~2012 -- present     & \bfseries Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries        \\
                         & \lipsum[66]                                          \\[5pt]
Sept.~2011 -- Apr.~2012  & \bfseries Intern Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries \\
                         & \lipsum*[66]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Just ensure that the right column cell has at least two lines, which should be fairly simple to do.

The trick is to convince TeX that the left column cells have no depth under the baseline: the contents is absorbed by means of Martin Scharrer's `collcell` and put into a `\parbox` that we give vertical size zero.

[image]

Of course there's an easier solution:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}!{\VRule}p{0.8\textwidth}}
June~2012 -- present     &
 \textbf{Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries}\newline
 \lipsum[66]
\\[5pt]
Sept.~2011 -- Apr.~2012  &
 \textbf{Intern Pixel Pusher at Vandalay Industries}\newline
 \lipsum*[66]
\end{tabular}
```

(Use Werner's method for getting the full line width.)