# Missing \item when compiling my resume

Tags: errors, cv, resume

I've building my resume using [`resume.cls`](http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/curriculum_vitaes/4/resume.cls), and I keep getting an error. However, it doesn't seem to be consistent:

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins
\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Experience}

\begin{rSubsection}{EMPLOYER}{DATES}{Web Developer}{LOCATION}
    One item.\\
    Another item.\\
    Yet another item.\\
    The last item.
\end{rSubsection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSubsection}{EMPLOYER}{DATES}{Developer and Sysadmin}{LOCATION}
    Item.\\
    Oh look, another item.\\
    Last item.
\end{rSubsection} % <-- error here

\end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting an error saying it's missing an `\item` on the line I marked above. The subsection above doesn't have any items, so why am I getting an error here?

Related description on Latextemplates.com: [Medium Length Professional CV](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv)

Comment: By the way, you should name the question in a more informative way. *Odd LaTeX error* could be the title of more than a half of the questions here in TeX.SE.

Comment: Beside what egreg has written in his answer: The class uses `\bf` and therefore let me quote this: “Please note that the `\it`, `\bf`, etc. font macros are deprecated because they do not use the new font selection scheme introduced with LaTeX2e. Please use `{\itshape ..}`, `{\bfseries ..}` or `\textit{..}`, `\textbf{..}` instead. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)
and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361)
for more information.”

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class you're using is not very well written.

Change line 117 as shown below:

```
117   \end{list}\par
118   \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
```

(line 118 is added for clarity; don't add the line numbers, of course).

The missing `\par` is the problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks egreg. I downloaded the template from some website. I'll change that, cheers.

Comment: Your answer is over a year old now, but after an hour of struggling with my resume, Google finally turned it up.  It worked like a charm!  Thanks so much for contributing the community, as it really helps all of us future-people.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to egreg's comment the  example document demonstrates that the rSubsection environment is a *list* the intended usage is

```
\begin{rSubsection}{ACME, Inc}{October 2010 - Present}{Web Developer}{Palo Alto, CA}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.
\item Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero Adobe Coldfusion egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue.
\item Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem Microsoft SQL lacinia consectetur.
\item Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat JavaScript sagittis.
\item Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bash bibendum purus convallis nulla ultrices ultricies.
\end{rSubsection}
```

Your example is a list with no `\item` and so (for once) the missing item error is related to a missing `\item`.

Comment: Sometimes those error messages are informative, eh? :)

Comment: Yeah, adding the `\item` works, but why doesn't it throw an error for the first block without `\items`?