# define an global variable; error ! Use of \@ doesn't match its definition

Tags: macros, titles

I want to define some variable for my IPE template, such as the title, affiliation and author etc. The code is listed below. However when I compile it using `pdflatex`, it does not show the result what the `\def` variable should be. When I remove the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, it issued a error message "! Use of \@ doesn't match its definition."

Any solutions ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\def\title#1{\def\@title{#1}} % Title 
\def\displaytitle#1{\def\@displaytitle{#1}} % Display Title
\def\displayauthor#1{\def\@displayauthor{#1}} % Display author
\def\displayaffiliation#1{\def\@displayaffiliation{#1}} % Display affiliation
\makeatother

\title{This is a presentation}%
\displayauthor{Liu Benyuan}%
\displayaffiliation{The Automatic Target Recognition (ATR) Laboratory}%
\displaytitle{Compressive Sensing via Block Sparse Bayesian Learning : Theory and Applications}%

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{736pt}
\vspace*{.5em}
\begin{minipage}{650pt}\Large
\textcolor{red}{
{\bf \@displayauthor{}}~~$\cdot$~~{\bf \@displayaffiliation{}}~\hfill$\cdot$\hfill~{\bf NUDT}} \\
\textcolor{blue}{
\bf \@displaytitle{}\hfill \today{}}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{8em}
\vspace*{.5em}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beside using `\makeatletter` before the minipage: You could also simply use command names without @. E.g. instead  of `\def\@displayaffiliation{#1}` do `\def\displayaffiliationcontent{#1}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @ulrike Fischer, Yes, your method can also work ! Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While your use of the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair in creating the definitions is done perfectly, you need to do the same if you reference these definitions elsewhere. So, "scoping" the `minipage` with another `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair solves your problem.

As reference, see [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)

Some other considerations:

- Use predefined lengths, rather than absolute ones. Perhaps using `\linewidth` rather than `736pt` would be more appropriate.
- For back-end macros, using `@` in the definitions are fine. However, if you're going to use definitions inside your document content, avoid the use of macros containing `@`, or build a user interface for that. For example,

  ```
  \def\printtitle{\@title}% Display title
  \def\printdisplaytitle{\@displaytitle}% Display title
  \def\printdisplayauthor{\@displayauthor}% Display author
  \def\printdisplayaffiliation{\@displayaffiliation}% Display affiliation
  ```

  Now you can use

  ```
  \textbf{\printdisplayauthor}~~$\cdot$~~%
    \textbf{\printdisplayaffiliation}~\hfill$\cdot$\hfill~%
    \textbf{NUDT} \
  ```
- Don't use the old font switches like `\bf` and `\it`. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Comment: yes! it works like a magic when I put \makeatletter and \makeatother around the minipage. But what if I want to reference the definitions somewhere in the main document,  I had to wrapper around, say \@displaytitle, with \makeatletter ... \makeatother, is there any way of working around this extra constrains ?

Comment: And that fixed width is for the layout of IPE for making representations. Thanks for the suggestions !

Comment: @liubenyuan: As mention in my answer, you should avoid that by creating "user interface macros" like \printdisplaytitle.