# Memoir class and Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, memoir, acm

I have

biblio.bib:

```
@article{XX,
title={{Title}},
author={Author},
journal={Journal Title},
volume=1,
number=11,
pages={1-2},
year=1666
}
```

And myfile.tex

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
   \usepackage{natbib} 
\begin{document}

   ...
   \cite{XX}
   ...

  \bibliography{biblio} 
  \bibliographystyle{acm} 

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: Class memoir Error: Font command \sc is not supported.

--- TeX said ---

See the memoir class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 {\sc
         Author}.
--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

Use \textsc, or \scshape{...}, or the oldfontcommands option
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `\documentclass[oldfontcommands]{memoir}`?

Comment: @Werner: No, I hadn't tried that. I get an error saying: `LaTeX Error: File '.cls' not found.`

Comment: @Thomas are you sure you typed exactly what Werner said?  (square brackets not braces for the `oldfontcommands` part)?

Comment: @AlanMunn: Ok, so I can get `\documentclass[oldfontcommands]{memoir}` to work. But I can't get `\documentclass[oldfontcommands][oneside]{memoir}` to work.

Comment: @Thomas: add all the options within on set of `[ ]` separated by commas. So `\documentclass[oneside,oldfontcommands]{memoir}`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `memoir` class enforces the use of proper font commands.  The old two-letter commands such as `\bf` and `\it`, `\sc`, etc. are problematic and now *very* old.  See

- [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/2693)

Unfortunately, many older bibliography styles still use the old font commands, and since their code is not trivial to modify, you are kind of stuck with them.  Luckily, `memoir` also provides an option to allow you to use the old font commands.  So for your example you need to load the class with this option (described in Sec.1.4 "Other options" of the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir?lang=en) for v3.7f):

```
\documentclass[oneside,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
```

Multiple options can be passed to a class or a package by putting them all inside one set of square brackets and separating them with commas.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried:

```
\renewcommand{\bf}{\textbf}
```

or

```
\renewcommand{\sc}{\textsc}
```

right after the `\usepackage{}` section and before `\begin{document}`?

It worked for me.

https://blogs.oracle.com/mociepka/entry/bibtex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think `\renewcommand` can do, since the problem is that `\sc` is *not* defined by default. It should be `\newcommand{\sc}{\scshape}`, also.

Comment: For me, `\renewcommand{\sc}{\scshape}` worked, and that was really what I needed, because my "enforcing" package was not memoir but komascript. I suspect that I had to use renewcommand instead of newcommand, because some of my other packages must have defined it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution involves changing the bibliography style file (`.bst`) file.

You will find one or more `\sc` command on it, which you can replace with `\textsc` to solve the problem.