# How to align text to the right in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I have a table of formulas, some have a description next to them, I want the equations to appear left flush and the text between parentheses right flush. I was writing it in the following way.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10 pt,twocolumn,fleqn]{article}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2.5cm}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{nopageno,array,graphicx,amsbsy,amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}       
\[{\bf P} = \int_{t_i}^{t_f}{\bf F}\,dt = \Delta{\bf p}\mbox{\hspace{7mm} (Impulse) }\]
\[\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{l}{2\mu}=cte \mbox{\hspace{7mm} (Kepler's Second Law) }\]
\end{document}
```

but the alignment is different for each equation.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You need to include your preamble. As it stands, your code does not produce flush left equations. I need to know how you are doing this in order to work out what the problem with `\tag*` is.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `\tag*` from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{P} = \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathbf{F}\,dt = \Delta \mathbf{p}\tag*{(Impulse) }
\]
\[
\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{l}{2\mu}=cte \tag*{(Kepler's Second Law) }
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that `\mathbf` is preferable to `\bf`; see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/2417) for more details.

Comment: I tried this way but now the equations are not left flush.

Comment: @MonicaG --- you didn't say anything about flush left equations! Perhaps you could edit your question to explain exactly what you want.

Comment: The complete document is 
\documentclass[letterpaper,10 pt,two column,fleqn]{article}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2.5cm}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{nopageno,array,graphicx,amsbsy,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{l}{2\mu}=cte \tag*{(Kepler's Second Law)}\]
....
\end{document}
Now it display the equations left flush and tags right flush.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another approach, currently set up to use the full `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\lreqn[2]{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{$\displaystyle#1$\hfill(#2)}\vspace{2ex}}
\begin{document}
\lreqn{\textbf{P} = \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\textbf{F}\,dt = \Delta\textbf{p}}{Impulse}
\lreqn{\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{l}{2\mu}=cte }{Kepler's Second Law}

This is the paragraph that follow the list
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could put it in a `tabular` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\def\extrarowheight{1.5em}
\let\ds\displaystyle
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\( \textbf{P} = \ds\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\textbf{F}\,dt = \Delta\textbf{p}\) & (Impulse) \\
\( \ds\frac{dA}{dt} = \ds\frac{l}{2\mu}=cte \) & (Kepler's Second Law) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `align` environment.

Here is an example.

*Edit: I have compiled this into a minimal working example, as per request. This will compile using XeLaTeX. I compiled this on a Mac running the latest MacTex distribution, but I think this should compile on most systems with XeLaTeX.*

*Edit^2: A bunch of includes are redundant, for instance, the enumerate include. I have copied the preamble from LaTeX-it.*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Helvetica}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Helvetica}
\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P} = \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathbf{F}\,dt = \Delta \mathbf{p}\tag*{(Impulse) }
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The align environment also gives you more fine grained control over the display of equations.

[image: sample equation using align]