# Alignment for Proof Justification in flalign* space?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

In problem 5 of my math homework I'm trying to typeset I'm having a gap in my knowledge about how to go about aligning the "Rule" justifications when I move from each step in my equation proof.  Is there a command I can use to just align everything right justify even if I'm trying to work with a centered/anchored equation in the flalgin* space?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathtools,amsfonts, enumitem, fancyhdr, color, comment, graphicx, environ, caption, subcaption}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{65pt}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{sol}
    {\emph{Solution:}
    }
    {
    \qed
    }
\specialcomment{com}{ \color{blue} \textbf{Comment:} }{\color{black}}

%for instructor comments while grading
\NewEnviron{probscore}{\marginpar{ \color{blue} \tiny Problem Score: \BODY \color{black} }}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lhead{A Curious LaTeX Student} 
\rhead{MAT 4170 \\ 9.8.19 \\ HW 2} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




\begin{problem}{5}
Let $S$ be the set of symmetries of an equilateral triangle.  We developed the following short list of rules that can be used to calculate any combination of elements of $S$.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Rule 1: $F^2=R^3=I$
        \item Rule 2: $FR=R^2F$
        \item Rule 3: $AI=IA$ where $A$ is any symmetry in $S$
        \item Rule 4: $A(BC)=(AB)C$ for any 3 symmetries $A,B,C$ in $S$.
        \item Rule 5: For each $A$ in $S$ there is a symmetry $A^{-1}$ in $S$ so that $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$
    \end{itemize}
Simplify the following expressions using the rules above.  Be sure to justify your steps using the rules. 
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item $F(FF)(FR)RR=$
    \item $F^2(RF)^3F^{-1}(R^2)^{-1}F^3=$
\end{enumerate}
\end{problem}

\begin{sol}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item \begin{flalign*}
            F(FF)(FR)RR &= F\textcolor{red}{(F^2)}(FR)RR\\
                        &= F\textcolor{red}{(I)}(FR)RR \hspace{2cm}\textrm{(Rule 1)}\\
                        &= F(FR)RR \hspace{2.55cm} \textrm{(Rule 3)}\\
                        &= \textcolor{red}{(FF)}\textcolor{red}{(RRR)} \hspace{2.3cm} \textrm{(Rule 4)}\\
                        &= (F^2)(R^3)\\
                        &= \textcolor{red}{(I)(I)} \hspace{3.55cm} \textrm{(Rule 1)}\\
                        &= \textcolor{red}{I}.      \hspace{4.3cm} \textrm{(Rule 3)}\\ 
            \end{flalign*}
    \item \begin{flalign*}
            (F^2)(RF)^3F^{-1}(R^2)^{-1}F^3 &= 
          \end{flalign*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{sol}

\begin{problem}{6}
Prove the following statements using Rules 1 through 5 above.  Be sure to include all steps and justify each step.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item $(RF)(RF)=I$
    \item $F=RFR$
\end{enumerate}
\end{problem}

\begin{sol}

\end{sol}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Do not alter anything below this line.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example more minimal. Curently it seem to contain a lot of code that is not really related to the alignment problem you describe. Please also add a sketch of the desired output.

Comment: @leandriis fixed

Comment: Probably you want to use `\tag{Rule 1}` instead of  `\hspace{2cm}\textrm{(Rule 1)}`?

Comment: @leandriis thank you, that worked!

Comment: As it is, your questions seems to be very similat to this one: [How to align text to the right in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131263/134144) Would you agree to close yours as a duplicate?

Comment: @leandriis how do I do that?