# How do you write text at the end of an equation?

Tags: formatting, horizontal

Like how do they get the bit where it says (By linearity of expectation) whilst still aligning the equations
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `\tag*{}` from `amsmath` as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131264/283484):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{b} \tag*{(Linear)} \\
    \mathbf{y} &= \mathbf{c} \tag*{(Trivial)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result of adding text to the right]