# Noindent in \thanks, left align

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, footnotes

I am using the following command in WinEdt to have the corresponding author contact info at the footnote. I used `\\` to have a new line since it was long.

I have two problems. First I need to left align letter "C" of the "Corresponding author" with the letter "E" of Email in the footnote. Second, I should interchange *,a with a,* in the 2nd line after first Author Name. Thanks and sorry if the first version of my question was not clear.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title {\bf  Title}
 \author[,a]{Author Name\thanks{Corresponding author. Tel.: +0 (000) 000 0000 ext. 00000; fax: +0 (000) 000 0000.\\ E-mail: email@123.com}}

\author[b]{Author Name}
\affil[a]{Department of , University of , Address, BB, CC}
\affil[b]{Department of , University of , Address, BB, CC}

\date{\today}
\begin {document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind changing the space between the line and the note, use \authorcr before "Corresponding author"

Answer (score 4):

In this instance, it is far easier to insert the appropriate space needed to horizontally align the two lines. The exact space is `1.8em`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}% http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk
\title{\textbf{Title}}
\author[,a]{Author Name\thanks{Corresponding author. Tel.: +0 (000) 000 0000 ext. 00000; fax: +0 (000) 000 0000.\\
  \hspace*{1.8em}E-mail: email@123.com}}
\author[b]{Author Name}
\affil[a]{Department of , University of , Address, BB, CC}
\affil[b]{Department of , University of , Address, BB, CC}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

<sub>For reference, also see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot Werner. Do you know how I can change \*,a with a,\*?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the [`article`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/article) class, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}
\settowidth{\thanksmarkwidth}{*}
\setlength{\thanksmargin}{-\thanksmarkwidth}

\title{Test}
\author{author\thanks{Corresponding author. Tel.: +0 (000) 000 0000 ext. 00000; fax: +0 (000) 000 0000.\newline E-mail: \texttt{email@123.com}}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited my question. The package you mentioned is not working with the ones that I have. I need letter "E" be right below letter C of the Corresponding author and not aligned with the \*. Also, I should interchange \*,a with a,\* in the 2nd line after first Author Name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kludge, and maybe not what you are looking for, but it seems to solve your second problem, while using the ideas above for the first:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % This line didn't work on my system...
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{authblk}

\title{The Title}
\author[b]{Author Name\textsuperscript{a,}\thanks{\noindent Corresponding author. Tel.: +0 (000) 000 0000 ext. 00000; fax: +0 (000) 000 0000.\\
\hspace*{1.8em}E-mail: email@123.com}\, and
Author Name}

\affil[a]{Department of , University of , Address, BB, CC}
\affil[b]{Department of , University of , Address, BB, CC}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle



\end{document}
```

[image: output]