# How to add a line-break inside a problem title?

Tags: line-breaking

I would like to state a problem in `LaTeX` with a somehow big title and I cannot find a way to separate the title in 2 lines. `LaTeX` keeps all this in one line. (Below is a sample code).

```
\begin{problem}[{\sc BlablaBlabla BlablaBlablaBlabla BlablaBlablaBlabla BlablaBlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlablaBlabla }]
....
\end{problem}
```

I tried to use `\\`, `\newline`, `\linebreak` and the `\protect` before these but nothing worked. `LaTeX` ignored the line breaking command completely.

E.g.

```
 \begin{problem}[{\sc BlablaBlabla BlablaBlablaBlabla BlablaBlablaBlabla \\ BlablaBlablaBlabla Blabla BlablaBlablaBlabla }]
 ...
 \end{problem}
```

Can someone please help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: How are you defining it?

Comment: Maybe interesting: [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/4918)

Comment: Furthermore it’s not really LaTeX-like to add the font (shape) in each `{proof}`. It’ll be better to change `{proof}` in a way that the fonts are set automatically …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine here:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\newtheorem{bla}{Problem}

\begin{document}
\begin{bla}[here is the first line\\ second line goes here] \lipsum[1]
\end{bla}
\begin{bla}[{\sc \lipsum[1]}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{bla}
\end{document}
```

[image]