# How to set font to Serif in Beamer title only

Tags: beamer, fonts, sans-serif

I want to use a serif font for the title in the title slide *only*.  I have tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[stillsansserifsmall, stillsansseriftext]{serif}
\title{\sc Great title} 
\date{\tiny Blah blah}  
\author{Fred} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

To be clear I want all the presentation in sans serif except for `\title{\sc Great title}`, which I want in serif.  In the above the title is sans serif though individual slide titles would be in serif.

Comment: Why can't you just put `{\rmfamily\scshape Title}` and not change the font theme?  Note the use of `\scshape` *not* `\sc` (which will not give the desired result). See [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361).

Comment: @AlanMunn that works.  Believe it or not I spent several hours searching for a solution. If you want to make it an answer I'll vote for it :-(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The problem

The problem arises because you are using *very old* and deprecated two-letter font commands, which, as you have discovered, yield unexpected effects when combined together.  Here's what you probably tried first:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{\rm\sc Great title} 
\date{\tiny Blah blah}  
\author{Fred} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame} 
 
\end{document}
```

If you compile this document, the title ends up in the sans font, and you also get the following warning saying that there is no sans small caps:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmss/m/n' instead
```

The reason for this is in the way the old two letter font commands work.  See the following for more discussion of this.

- [TeX FAQ on Two Letter Font Commands](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-2letterfontcmd)
- [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/2693)

### The solution

The solution is to use the proper font commands, `\rmfamily` and `\scshape` and then things behave as you expect:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{\rmfamily\scshape Great title} 
\date{\tiny Blah blah}  
\author{Fred} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame} 
 
\end{document}
```