# Move title to top of page but keep the top margin value

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, titles

Having a lot of problems with LaTeX at the moment. I need my article to have a top margin of 33mm, but for some reason my title page has a much larger margin. Is there a simple fix I have overlooked?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % formatting rules for the English language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % proper formatting for accented characters and non-standard characters such as pipelines
\usepackage[top=33mm, bottom=38mm, left=26mm, right=20mm]{geometry} % page layout
\usepackage{lmodern} % font formatting
\usepackage{float} % allow floating environments such as figures
\usepackage{amsmath} % math eqn formatting
\usepackage{amssymb} % math fonts
\title{\bf{\fontsize{14pt}{2pt} Title}}
\author{\fontsize{14pt}{2pt} Author names}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: The title need this space to be a decent title. But you can uglify it with some like `\title{\vspace{-3cm} ...}`

Comment: Why have you used -3cm?

Comment: Is only an example. Change -3cm for the negative length that you want. You can use also like -20pt or -1.5em or -3ex ...

Comment: The problem is I don't know how much extra space it is using. I can't see why it is using a different setting if I explicitly set the top margin to 33cm.

Comment: Add the `showframe` to `geometry` package to check how far is still from the top margin. The `\maketitle`  definition in `article.cls` add 2em because this is the usual in the finest journals. Adding a vertical space -2em should be enough to change this default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to correct some errors in your code:

1. Don't use `\bf` which is deprecated in LaTeX, but `\bfseries` or `\textbf` (see for example [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/27635))
2. With `12pt` as an option for the document class, use `\large` instead of `\fontsize{14pt}{2pt}` (BTW, it should be something like `\fontsize{14pt}{17pt}\selectfont`). The result is the same.

To have the title at the top of the page, you can patch the macro `\@maketitle` with the help of the command `\patchcmd` from the `etoolbox` package, that is, add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {\null\vskip 2em\begin{center}}
  {\centering}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {\end{center}}
  {}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

MWE (remove the option `showframe` from `geometry`, it is just to show that it works)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % formatting rules for the English language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % proper formatting for accented characters and non-standard characters such as pipelines
\usepackage[top=33mm, bottom=38mm, left=26mm, right=20mm, showframe]{geometry} % page layout
\usepackage{lmodern} % font formatting
\usepackage{float} % allow floating environments such as figures
\usepackage{amsmath} % math eqn formatting
\usepackage{amssymb} % math fonts

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {\null\vskip 2em\begin{center}}
  {\centering}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {\end{center}}
  {}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\title{\large\bfseries Title}
\author{\large Author names}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\droptitle` length that is defined in the  `titling`package. On another hand, there are several errors in your preamble: Firstly, the second argument to `\fontsize` is the value of the vertical space between two consecutive lines, so it should not be  smaller than the design size of the font itself. Usually, it is about 20 % larger. Secondly, if you do not add `\selectfont`, it's ineffective, as you can see with the following code: I've written a two-lines title, in the first of which I've "forgotten" to write \selectfont; it results in a first line that has the default size (\LARGE, about 20pt), not 14 pt.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel} % formatting rules for the English language
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % proper formatting for accented characters and non-standard characters such as pipelines
    \usepackage{lmodern} % font formatting
    \usepackage[english]{babel} % formatting rules for the English language
    \usepackage[top=33mm, bottom=38mm, left=26mm, right=20mm, showframe]{geometry} % page layout
    \usepackage{float} % allow floating environments such as figures
    \usepackage{amsmath} % math eqn formatting
    \usepackage{amssymb} % math fonts
    \usepackage{titling}
    \droptitle = -20mm
    \title{\bfseries\fontsize{14}{17} Title\\\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont A subtitle}%
    \author{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont Author names}
    \date{}
    \begin{document}

    \maketitle

    Blahblahblah…
    \end{document}
```

[image]