# LATEX: Error when use 'cline' in a table

Tags: tables, errors

I use latex to prepare exam sheets. I use the [`exam.cls` package](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/).

In the cover page, I created a table to include the question categories and their points:

```
\begin{table}[H]
   \centering
   \large
       \begin{tabular}{ l  l }
           \hline
           & \\
           \parbox[l]{10cm}{\bf Problem} & \parbox[l]{2.6cm}{\bf Points} \\
           \cline{1}
           & \\
       \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Unfortunately, when I use `\cline` in this table, I receive the following error message (when I remove `\cline`, the error message disappears):

```
Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 19--24
[][]
Runaway argument?
1\@nil  \\ & \\ \end {tabular} \end {table}
! Paragraph ended before \@cline was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.38
```

How can I solve this error?

BTW, here are the packages that I use

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\cline{<from>-<to>}` requires you to specify a column `<from>` which the horizontal rule starts `<to>` where it ends, even if `<from>` = `<to>`. In your case, you probably want to use `\cline{1-1}`. Here's a code snippet of your table that simplifies your code a little:

```
{\noindent\large
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\begin{tabular}{ p{10cm} p{2.6cm} }
  \hline
  \textbf{Problem} & \textbf{Points} \\
  \cline{1-1}
  & \\
\end{tabular}
}
```

Some suggestions:

- You don't need a `table` environment in order to set a `tabular`.
- A change to `\arraystretch` spaces out the lines inside the `tabular`. See [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764).
- The `p{<len>}`-style column avoids the hassle of inserting a `\parbox` within cells to obtain the same output.
- Use `\textbf{...}` or `{\bfseries ...}` to set something in **bold**. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)