# Head of table - combination of cells

Tags: tables

How to make head of table like in the picture? Thank you
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{title}
    \footnotesize\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
        \toprule
        \multirowcell{1}[-1pt]{Element} & \multirowcell{3}[-1pt]{\citep{M}} & \multirowcell{2}[-1pt]{\citep{C}} & \multirowcell{1}[-1pt]{\citep{R}}& \multirowcell{3}[-1pt]{\citep{P}} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{POWR analýza} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Řešení světelných křivek a RV} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{CFF} } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model} \\

& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Řešení I} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Řešení II} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Řešení III} &  &  & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{malá hmotnost} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{střední hmotnost} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{velká hmotnost} \\        

        \midrule
& & & & & & & & & &
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage

\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\anote}{}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^*$}}

\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsfonts}       % matematické fonty
\usepackage{amsthm}         % sazba vět, definic apod.
\usepackage{bbding}         % balíček s nejrůznějšími symboly
                % (čtverečky, hvězdičky, tužtičky, nůžtičky, ...)
\usepackage{bm}             % tučné symboly (příkaz \bm)
\usepackage{fancyvrb}       % vylepšené prostředí pro strojové písmo
\usepackage{indentfirst}    % zavede odsazení 1. odstavce kapitoly
\usepackage{natbib}         % zajištuje možnost odkazovat na literaturu
                % stylem AUTOR (ROK), resp. AUTOR [ČÍSLO]
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % zajistí přidání seznamu literatury,
                            % obrázků a tabulek do obsahu
\usepackage{icomma}         
\usepackage{booktabs}       % lepší vodorovné linky v tabulkách
\usepackage{paralist}       % lepší enumerate a itemize
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.25ex}
\usepackage{cellspace, multirow, tabularx}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\stack[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{#1}}}
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\mbox{\normalfont\AA}}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \bgroup%
   \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}%
   \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}%
   \egroup}
%%% code block to handle the OP's follow-up question -- see
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112002/5001 for the source
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
% Change the `-` delimiter to an active character
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}  % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| *{4}{C|} >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}C| >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C| *{3}{C|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{M} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & R & \multicolumn{3}{ c|}{P} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV} & 
\mytab{POWR\\analýza} & 
\mytab{Řešení\\světelných\\křivek a RV} & 
CFF & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Model} \\
\cline{1-3} \cline{7-9}
Řešení I & Řešení II & Řešení III & & & & malá hmotnost & střední hmotnost & velká hmotnost\\
\hline\hline
& & & & & & & & \\
\hline
& & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it important that the underlying 9 columns have the same widths? Should line-wrapping be allowed inside the cells?

Comment: No, columns don't have same widths - it depends on situation. Yes line-wrapping be allowed inside the cells.

Comment: You should really, really try *much harder* not to load packages more than once. What exactly are you trying to achieve by loading `amsmath`, `graphicx`, `array`, `babel`, `multirow`, `xcolor`, `lmodern` [3 times!], `textcomp`, `bm`, `dcolumn`, `tocbibind`, `tabularx` [3 times!], and `ragged2e` twice or even three times? Absolutely nothing good -- and quite possibly something bad -- is going to result from this bad habit. After you've cleaned out the duplicates, you should probably also examine whether all packages that remain are even needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \bgroup%
   \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}%
   \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}%
   \egroup}
%%% code block to handle the OP's follow-up question -- see
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112002/5001 for the source
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
% Change the `-` delimiter to an active character
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother
%%% end of additional code

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}  % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| *{4}{C|} 
    >{\hsize=1.3\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C|    
    >{\hsize=0.7\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C| 
    *{3}{C|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{M} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & R & \multicolumn{3}{ c|}{P} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV} & 
\mytab{POWR\\analýza} & 
\mytab{Řešení\\světelných\\křivek a RV} & 
CFF & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Model} \\
\cline{1-3} \cline{7-9}
Řešení I & Řešení II & Řešení III & & & & malá hmotnost & střední hmotnost & velká hmotnost\\
\hline\hline
& & & & & & & & \\
\hline
& & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And this please: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnVjm.png ? It depens on position of \usepackage in some way?

Comment: @Elisabeth - Not knowing what you wrote in terms of LaTeX code, I have no idea how to interpret the error messages you're getting. For sure, it look like your code may differ significantly from what I wrote above.

Comment: I added the whole code in my question.

Comment: @Elisabeth - The problem arises from your use of the `babel` package with the option `czech`. Please see [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112002/5001) to the query [Slovak (and Czech) babel gives problems with cmidrule and cline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111999/5001). In particular, do follow his instructions under the "A less invasive hack..." subheader, i.e., the code block that starts with `\usepackage{regexpatch}` and ends with `\makeatother`. I've also posted an update to my answer, to show how to make this patch work for the code shown here.

Comment: @Elisabeth - Given your font size and page size settings, you should also change `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` to `\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}`, and change `\mytab{Řešení\\světelných\\křivek a RV}` to `\mytab{Řešení\\světel-\\ných kři-\\vek a RV}`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to follow your advice but when I tri to compile what is now in EDIT in my question, there is mistakes all the time. What I did wrong please?

Comment: @Elisabeth - The new problem appears to be related to your use of the `cellspace` package, which is something that's not related to my answer. If you have a new question about how to make the `cellspace` package compatible with the rest of your code, you should post a new query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86784/discussion-between-elisabeth-and-mico).

Comment: I editted it in my question

Comment: @Elisabeth - Your use of the `cellspace` package was not disclosed in the version of the query upon which I constructed my answer. For what it's worth, I'm not familiar with the `cellspace` package. In particular, I have no idea how it interacts with one or more of the many other packages you (still) load. That's why I suggested you post a new query, in which you focus solely on the `cellspace` (in)compatibility matter.

Comment: It works without cellspace. Thank you very much

Comment: @Elisabeth - Why were you loading the `cellspace` package in the first place? Packages that aren't used shouldn't be loaded...

Comment: I had need it somewhere but then I deleted it and forgot to remove the package.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{title}
\footnotesize\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{M} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & R & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{P} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{~}& &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}\\
    \cline{1-3} \cline{7-9}
    & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 & col8  &col9 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. And please, what does this error mean 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JDlp.png? It appears when I add it to main file.

Comment: @Elisabeth Its difficult say without seeing the complete code. Please see this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166655/28557