# Parse markdown automatically (just emphasis) without luatex

Tags: text-manipulation, markdown

I want to parse markdown emphasis automatically in XeLaTeX. This basically means converting asterisks either side of a word into the \emph{word} that LaTeX uses. I know that more complex Markdown parsing is impossible, but this seems quite simple. Unfortunately, I don't know how to go about replacing something that is not a command.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15374/4427