# Modifying a template fancy chapter

Tags: fncychap

I am using roughly the following setup

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}                   
\usepackage[bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\begin{document}
*some stuff*
\mainmatter
\input{Chapters/Chapter1}
etc.
\end{document}
```

I think the "Lenny" chapter style looks really nice. I would only like to change one minor detail: the title of the chapter is not printed boldfaced. For every chapter it is easy to change this: I simply write `\chapter{{\bf TITLE}}`. However, I would also like to have this for the Table of Contents and "Symbols" pages. How to do this?

Comment: Please: Wherever you learned about `\bf` - burn that book. Commands like `\bf` have been deprecated since the release of LaTeX2e, which was in 1994! See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5763.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Package `fncychap` uses those commands a lot (according to both manual, sources, and my experiments), in gems like `\Huge\bfseries\rm` (used by the `Lenny` style for the chapter title), so that bold essentially never works. (In fact, actually using bold makes IMHO most provided designs worse).
On the other hand, at the start of fncychap's manual, the author admits he's no expert and asks for feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to you, I find the Lenny chapter style one of the ugliest I've ever seen.

Add

```
\ChTitleVar{\Huge\bfseries}
```

to your preamble.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ChTitleVar{\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A nice title}
\end{document}
```

By the way, `hyperref` should be loaded last.

[image]

You may slightly improve the appearance by not using Helvetica and Times.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ChTitleVar{\Huge\bfseries}
\ChNameVar{\large\bfseries}
\ChNumVar{\fontsize{60}{62}\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A nice title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\bfseries` in `\ChNumVar` you might want `\fontseries{b}\selectfont`.

[image]

However, it's still irremediably ugly.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Any suggestions on what style you like way better than Lenny? You might be able to convince me :)

Comment: @Funzies You find several chapter heading styles with `texdoc MemoirChapStyles` (available also [on line](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf))