# How can I narrow down these gaps?

Tags: spacing, cv, resume

[image]

I am writing my curriculum vitae, but I have one question.

In the first image, there are spaces between different sections.

(Between contact and phone, between education and Seoul~~,....)

Thus, I want to narrow down these gaps.

How can I solve this problem??

```
\documentclass[margin,line,letterpaper,11pt]{res}

\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\setlength{\topmargin}{0.1in} \setlength{\textheight}{11in}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6in} \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.55in}

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.55in}

\oddsidemargin -.25in \evensidemargin -.49in \textwidth=5.4in

\newcommand{\ts}{\textsuperscript}

\newcommand{\block}[1]{
    \vspace{.1in} \section{\sc #1}
}

\newcommand{\subblock}[1]{
    \vspace{-.2in}\subsection*{#1}
}

\newenvironment{enum}{
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=5mm]
    \setlength{\itemsep}{1mm}
}{
    \end{enumerate}
}


\begin{document}


\name{\sc \LARGE  } 

\begin{resume}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\block{Contact}
Phone:  \\
Email: 
\\\vspace*{-6mm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\block{Education}

University : \\

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\block{Other\\ Activities}

Club : \\


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you need to indent code by 4 spaces to format it. (Or highlight and hit the `{}` button.) Please complete the code so that your example is a complete, small document people can copy-paste-compile. Note that you ought not use `\bf`, `\sf` etc. - they are deprecated more than 20 years ago. Use `\bfseries`, `\textbf{}` etc. instead.

Comment: Also `times` is deprecated and ought not be used and you seem to have conflicting settings for your page layout dimensions. Consider using `geometry` to handle this. Oh, and you need some `%`s, too.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Btw: `\bf` has been deprecated for more than two decades now. I suggest you read a recent LaTeX documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`res`](http://ctan.org/pkg/res), this width is given by `\sectionwidth`. Under the `margin` document class option, the default width is `1.3in`. You can adjust this to suit your needs using

```
\newsectionwidth{<len>}
```

where `<len>` is the new, desired width of each "section". Try, for example, a width of `1in` or `.7\sectionwidth` (70% of the existing `\sectionwidth`).

Other things mentioned in comments:

- `\sc` and `\bf` are deprecated switches. Use `\scshape` and `\bfseries` instead. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)
- Consider using an up-to-date CV package like [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv), or write your own from scratch using `article`.