# Generating a 3x3 payoff matrix (Game-Theory)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Been working on some economics lately, and was able to figure out how to put together some 2x2 payoff matrix's but not sure how to go about doing a 3x3. I would like to keep the same general idea if possible, i.e. the tikz picture.

Here is what I have used to generate a 2x2.

```
%third matrix
%learn how to do 3x3
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,every odd row/.style={align=right},every evenrow/.style={align=left},every node/.style={text width=1.5cm},row sep=0.2cm,column sep=0.2cm] (m) {
2&\bf{3}\\
4&\bf{2}\\
-1&\bf{0}\\
\bf{6}&0\\
};
\draw (m.north east) rectangle (m.south west);
\draw (m.north) -- (m.south);
\draw (m.east) -- (m.west);

\coordinate (a) at ($(m.north west)!0.25!(m.north east)$);
\coordinate (b) at ($(m.north west)!0.75!(m.north east)$);
\node[above=5pt of a,anchor=base] {Left};
\node[above=5pt of b,anchor=base] {Right};

\coordinate (c) at ($(m.north west)!0.25!(m.south west)$);
\coordinate (d) at ($(m.north west)!0.75!(m.south west)$);
\node[left=2pt of c,text width=1cm]  {Up};
\node[left=2pt of d,text width=1cm]  {Down};

\node[above=18pt of m.north] (firm b) {Column};
\node[left=1.6cm of m.west,align=center,anchor=center] {Row};

%\node[above=5pt of firm b]  {Payoff Matrix};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: The question is....?

Comment: @HarishKumar: I think the OP wants to know how to modify his code for a 3 by 3 matrix.

Comment: @Shahab And how does a `3 x 3` matrix look like? I don't know game theory!

Comment: @HarishKumar: Basically 9 boxes instead of 4.

Comment: @Shahab hehe. I think I know that much ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look at [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/will-two-letter-font-style-commands-bf-it-ever-be-resurrected-in-latex)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myrowhead{{"Left","Up","Front"}}
\def\mycolhead{{"Right","Down","Back"}}

\matrix[matrix of math nodes,draw,
every odd row/.style={align=right},every evenrow/.style={align=left},
nodes={text width=1.5cm},row sep=0.2cm,column sep=0.2cm] 
          (m) {2&3&6\\4&2&-1\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0\\2&3&6\\4&2&-1\\};
\foreach\x[count=\xi from 2,evaluate={\xx=int(2*\x);\xxi=int(\xx+1)}] in {1,2}{
  \draw ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.north) -- ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.south);
  \draw ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.west) -- ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.east);
}
\foreach\x in{0,1,2}{
  \node[text depth=0.25ex,above=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.north east)$) 
     {\pgfmathparse{\myrowhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
  \node[left=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.south west)$) 
     {\pgfmathparse{\mycolhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
}


\node[above=18pt of m.north] (firm b) {Column};
\node[left=1.6cm of m.west,align=center,anchor=center] {Row};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you need `.append style` instead of `.style` to make keep the node entries math.  The OP had some entries `\bf`, that ought to be `\mathbf`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Oops. I didn't even pay attention. Fixed now via `nodes`. Thanks. I'll leave the node ornaments to OP though.

Comment: The \bf is entirely for me just highlighting the number for game purposes.