# why is there no space after \sc when using it as a macro?

Tags: spacing

Here is a MWE that explains it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\scmacro}{{\sc macro}}

\begin{document}

why is there no space after \scmacro even though there is space in the document?

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\sc` is old style. Please don't use it, even in a group

Comment: See [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361)

Comment: Just don't reinvent the wheel and use `\textsc{macro}`. If you need a command for it, just do `\newcommand{\scmacro}{\textsc{macro}}` and use it as `\scmacro{}`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\scmacro\` or `\scmacro{}` or `\textsc{macro}` and replace `\sc` with `\scshape`

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\scmacro}{{\scshape macro}}


\begin{document}

why is there no space after \scmacro\ or \scmacro{} or \textsc{macro} even though there is space in the document?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `{}` after a command to ensure that you'll have a space in the document produced.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\scmacro}{{\sc macro}}

\begin{document}

why is there no space after \scmacro{} even though there is space in the document?

\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, did you check the output? I think you have `{}` in the wrong place. Plus `\sc` has been deprecated for 20 years.

Comment: I think that what OP needs is `\textsc{macro}`, not `\sc{}`. Anyway it should be `\scmacro{}`.

Comment: @egreg Yes I interverted the `{}`. What should be used instead of `\sc`