# Writing sub-and superscript in mathmode

Tags: math-mode

i want to Write sub-and superscript in math mode  but not italic.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \begin{document}
            % using mathmode sub- and supperscrit.
 \begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}^{T}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}_{xx}
\end{equation}
        % I can do it using /bf but it makes it is also bold.

        \begin{equation}
\bf{M}^{T}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\bf{M}_{xx}
\end{equation}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\rm` instead of `\bf`? Incidentally, you mention material in subscripts and superscripts; what about the material in the "normal" positions? Should that material be rendered in (math) bold automatically?

Comment: (1) `\bf` is a switch, thus does not take arguments, (2) `\bf` switches to the text font, not wat you want, (3) either use `\mathbf` or (IMO better) load the `bm` package and use `\bm{M}` as it will be bold and italic mah font

Comment: @Mico, infact it is equation environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display material in sub- and superscripts using roman/upright rather than italic letters, you should render the main material (i.e., what's on the main math axis) using roman/upright letters as well.

One way to render *all* math material with upright letters on a document-wide basis is to load the `mathastext` package:

```
\usepackage{mathastext}
```

Another method for achieving this look on a document-wide basis would be to issue the instructions

```
\everymath{\rm}
\everydisplay{\rm}
```

in the preamble.

*Addendum*: The commands `\bf` and `\rm` are considered deprecated in LaTeX2e documents. They do happen to work -- more or less as one would expect they should work in a Plain-TeX document -- *if* one uses one of the "standard" LaTeX document classes (`article`, `report`, and `book`) or a document class that's based on one of the standard classes. If you use one of the Koma-Script document classes, though, you'll get a warning message. Finally, `\bf` and `\rm` aren't defined at all in the `memoir` document class. For general portability of one's code across document classes, the `\bm` and `\rm` macros shouldn't be used in a LaTeX document anymore.

Comment: `\rm` should warrant a downvote.

Comment: @egreg - Why? As explained in more detail in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304312/5001), the standard LaTeX classes define `\rm` as follows: `\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}`. Thus, `\rm` in *math mode* acts like `\mathrm`.

Comment: Try that with `memoir` ;-)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I won't upvote either. This is wrong. But, since the upshape characters chosen by `\mathrm` generally correspond to family 0, you should know what to do.

Comment: @daleif - The OP used the `article` class in the MWE. This made me think it's OK to use a definition of `\rm` that *is* provided by the `article` class.

Comment: @egreg - My preference, for sure, would be to use the `mathastext` package.

Comment: I still agree with egreg users should not be encouraged to use `\rm` in latex, plus doesn't it still give you a warning in `article`?

Comment: @daleif - `\sc` and `\sl` *in math mode* will generate a LaTeX warning, but `\rm`, `\bf`, `\sf`, `\tt`, and `\it` do not.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, odd.