# How do I get mathbf by default?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, boldmath

I am presenting a paper (not mine) in which almost all math symbols are in `\mathbf`. I know I can put `\boldmath` in the preamble but it does not typesets it as the regular `\mathbf` does (upright).

So, is there a way to change the behavior of boldmath macro so that it typesets everything in `\mathbf` (except, possibly, greek letters for which the behavior of `\boldmath` is great).

And, if so, what command should I use when I want something in particular to be back to the usual non-bold italic font?

P.S. I also noticed the `\boldmath` command changes all other symbols such as operators and logicals. I would like them to stay in their non-bold usual way. Maybe at this point it would be easier to just change math font, I just don't know how to do it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Answer (score 10):

Change the math code of the letters; some brute force is necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{boldletters}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{boldletters} % not to waste a family
\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`a}
\DeclareMathSymbol{b}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`b}
\DeclareMathSymbol{c}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`c}
\DeclareMathSymbol{d}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`d}
\DeclareMathSymbol{e}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`e}
\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`f}
\DeclareMathSymbol{g}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`g}
\DeclareMathSymbol{h}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`h}
\DeclareMathSymbol{i}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`i}
\DeclareMathSymbol{j}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`j}
\DeclareMathSymbol{k}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`k}
\DeclareMathSymbol{l}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`l}
\DeclareMathSymbol{m}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{n}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{o}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`o}
\DeclareMathSymbol{p}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`p}
\DeclareMathSymbol{q}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{r}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`r}
\DeclareMathSymbol{s}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`s}
\DeclareMathSymbol{t}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`t}
\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`u}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`v}
\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`w}
\DeclareMathSymbol{x}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`x}
\DeclareMathSymbol{y}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{z}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{B}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{C}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{D}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{E}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{F}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{G}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`G}
\DeclareMathSymbol{H}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`H}
\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{J}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`J}
\DeclareMathSymbol{K}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{L}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`L}
\DeclareMathSymbol{M}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{N}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{O}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{P}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Q}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`Q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{R}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`R}
\DeclareMathSymbol{S}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`S}
\DeclareMathSymbol{T}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{U}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`U}
\DeclareMathSymbol{V}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`V}
\DeclareMathSymbol{W}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`W}
\DeclareMathSymbol{X}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Y}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Z}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`Z}

\begin{document}

$a+b=\mathnormal{c}$

\end{document}
```

For the occasional letter in the default style, use `\mathnormal` as shown.

[image]

With some less brute force:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{boldletters}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{boldletters} % not to waste a family

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\def\DMS@#1{\DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`#1}}
\count@=`a \advance\count@\m@ne
\@whilenum\count@<`z\do{
  \advance\count@\@ne
  \lccode`A=\count@
  \lowercase{\DMS@{A}}
}
\count@=`A \advance\count@\m@ne
\@whilenum\count@<`Z\do{
  \advance\count@\@ne
  \uccode`a=\count@
  \uppercase{\DMS@{a}}
}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a+b=\mathnormal{c}$

$abcdefgz$

$ABCDEFGZ$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\loop...\repeat` and not `\@whilenum`?

Comment: @HenriMenke Laziness. Happier, now? `;-)`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using one of "basic" LaTeX document classes -- `article`, `report`, and `book` -- or a document class that is built on one of these classes, you could proceed as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\everymath{\bf}
\everydisplay{\bf}
\begin{document}
$a^2+b^2=c^2$

$\cos^2{\theta}+\sin^2(\theta)=1 $
\end{document}
```

Observe that `a`, `b`, `c`, `1` and `2` are rendered in bold, whereas `+`, `=`, `cos`, `sin` and `\theta` are not. I understand that's the look you want. Please advise if I misinterpreted your requirements.

Aside: Do note that `\bf` -- as well as `\it`, `\rm`, `\tt`, `\sf`, `\sl`, and `\sc` -- is nowadays (rightly!) considered deprecated in a LaTeX document and that its use is even frowned upon. For sure, some LaTeX document classes (such as `memoir`) no longer even provide a definition for `\bf`. However, as is explained in more detail in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304312/5001) to the query [Is there any reason not to use \let to redefine a deprecated control sequence to the currently recommended one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304311/5001), you're actually alright using `\bf` *if* you use one of the "standard" document classes. More precisely, `\bf` will then behave exactly as it would in a PlainTeX document. In particular, `\bf` in an inline or display math setting is automatically re-interpreted as `\mathbf`.

You will get rid of the automatic-bold look as soon as the need for it has expired, right? :-)