# `\rm` control sequence undefined in custom class but works for `report`, how to find the problem

Tags: fonts, errors, obsolete

I am using custom class and when I use `${\rm test}$` I get complaint that it is `Undefined control sequence.` It does not in text mode either. I tried searching through the `cls` file and other relevant linked files for `\rm` but I can never find where it would be removed, actaully, it is used in the class as:

```
\newcommand\@makecopyrightpage{
   \ColumnSave
   \pagenumbering{roman}
   \setcounter{page}{2}
   %\thispagestyle{empty} 
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \null
   \vfill
   \if@copyright
      \begin{center}
         %\normalsize \rm Copyright \copyright\ \@copyrightyear
         %\ifx\@copyrightyear\@degreeyear\else , \@degreeyear \fi
         %\ by \@author \\
         %\@copyrightinfo
         \normalsize \normalfont \copyright\  \@copyrightyear  \hspace{1pt}
         \@author \\
      \end{center}
   \fi
   \vfill
   \ColumnRestore
}
```

the only other places that `\rm` can be found in the class:

```
\def\ps@headings{\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenfoot{}%     No feet.
\def\@oddhead{\hbox {}\slshape \rightmark \hfil \rm\thepage}% Heading.
\def\chaptermark##1{\markright {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}}}

% Definition of 'myheadings' page style.
%
\def\ps@myheadings{\def\@oddhead{\hbox{}\slshape\rightmark \hfil \rm\thepage}%
\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenhead{\rm \thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark\hbox {}}%
\def\@evenfoot{}\def\sectionmark##1{}\def\subsectionmark##1{}}
```

When i switch to `\documentclass{report}` everything works. How can i investigate where it got lost?

Comment: `\rm` has been deprecated and not defined by default in latex since latex2e was released in 1993. `report` class defines it for compatibility with documents written in the 1980s but other classes may not.

Comment: The `\rm` command has been deprecated for 25 years. Some document classes define it for back compatibility. There are classes and packages around that use `\rm` and siblings: it's a sure sign that they should be avoided.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So it has to be explicitly defined in the class for it to work, thus if I find it definition in the `report` class and copy it over, it should do the trick?

Comment: use `\rmfamily` or if you really must, copy the definition of `\rm` from report, which is `\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}`

Comment: yes that would work but not using `\rm` would be better.

Comment: Does the postings [Why \rm in math mode works in some tex editors and not in others?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339698/5001) and [Is there any reason not to use \let to redefine a deprecated control sequence to the currently recommended one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304311/5001) answer your query?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I read in Lamport's book that `\rmfamily` does not work in math mode (which is the whole purpose for me to need `\rm`). So what is there in math mode? Also, if it is undefined in the class, how can the class use it  in the above code?

Comment: `\mathrm{zzz}` in math mode but none of the uses you show in your question are in math.

Comment: @leosenko - Lamport's book deals with LateX2.09, i.e., the version of LaTeX available up until 1993. As David Carlisle wrote in an earlier comment, LaTeX2e has been around since 1994.

Comment: That is the _definition_ of `\rm` copied from report, it says to use `\normalfont\rmfamily` in text and `\mathrm` in math.

Comment: @Mico er no, not unless you have a very old 1980s copy of Lamport. Lamport's book is still the official documentation for 2e.

Comment: @Mico if there is a other good book, i am all ears but sincerely, getting any good information on `TeX` function declaration and how they work is really a pain... I have found Lamport's book to be the best so far covering `Latex` as well as some `Tex` commands.

Comment: `texdoc clsguide` is the document that comes with latex that describes how to write a class and also how to define `\rm` if you really must. See section 6.4

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I guess I'm guilty of having "a very old 1980s copy" of Lamport's book...

Comment: @Mico we're all getting too old for this game:-)

Comment: See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?
](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/).  Of the books shown there, Kopka & Daly remains my perennial favorite.  Not only a good resource for the beginner, it remains useful as a highly functional reference, with good examples and clear explanations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for roman in math in LaTeX is `$\mathrm{test}$` not `${\rm test}$`.

`\rm` has not been defined in LaTeX since LaTeX2e was released in 1993.

As described in `clsguide` the guide to writing latex classes that comes with latex, you could define `\rm` via

```
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
```

and the `report` class does this, however that was over compatibility concerns with documents written in the 1980s. No documents written this century should be using `\rm` so for a class being written now it is better *not* to define `\rm` and assume that the document has correct markup. That way bad markup in the document is easily found and corrected.