# How to modify a math-mode column type to use teletype letters by default?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, arrays

With normal text, I have the choice between `\texttt{…}`, which applies the font change to an argument, and `\ttfamily`, which applies it to the rest of the group.

In math mode, I have the former, with `\mathtt{…}`. What is the equivalent of `\ttfamily` in math mode?

(Why can’t I use `\mathtt`? Because I want to apply the change in a `>{…}` column spec, together with `lhs2Tex`.)

Comment: Are you using one of the "standard" LaTeX document classes (article, report, book) or a document class that's based on one of these classes? If so, `>{\tt}` works just fine in math mode.

Comment: @Mico actually that or in general `\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}` is perhaps a cleaner answer than mine (although it's the same thing really) you should probably post as answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Done. :-)

Comment: @Mico voted! (somehow I hadn't seen your comment, although the site says it was posted 20min before my answer:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably an abuse of syntax  but anyway you can use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


$\mathtt{\global\count1\fam}\fam\count1 abc=xyz$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use one of the "standard" LaTeX document classes (`article`, `report`, `book`) or a document class that's built on one of these classes, you could use `>{\tt}` as the "prefix" to the relevant column type. A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{>{\tt}c}
   aaaa
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

---

The KOMA-Script document classes (e.g., `scrartcl`, `scrreport`, `scrbook`) and the `memoir` class no longer define `\tt`. If you use one of these classes, you will also need to provide the following directive in the preamble:

```
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
```

as well as `\usepackage{array}`. A suitably modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} % or: \documentclass{memoir}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{>{\tt}c}
   aaaa
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting – how does `\DeclareOldFontCommand` turn a argument-expecting function `\mathtt` into one that extends to the end?

Comment: For more on `\DeclareOldFontCommand`, see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304312/5001) to the query [Is there any reason not to use \let to redefine a deprecated control sequence to the currently recommended one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304311/5001) (Shameless self-citation alert!) See, in particular, the discussion, toward the end, of what `\@fontswitch` does. Basically, in a math context, `\@fontswitch` changes `\mathtt` from behaving like taking an argument to behaving like a switch, i.e., not taking an argument.