# How to make **hello** produce hello in italics?

Tags: catcodes

I know I can make `*hello*` produce hello in bold typeface.  But how would I, in addition, make `**hello**` produce hello in italics?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup\lccode`\~=`* \lowercase{\endgroup\def~#1~}{{\bfseries #1}}
\catcode`*=13

\begin{document}
*this is bold typeface*                 % works
**this should be italic typeface**      % how to do this?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is using LuaLaTeX an option for you?

Comment: Sure, though I'd also value a regular latex answer.

Comment: Are you porting Markdown to LaTeX ?

Comment: No, I am not...

Comment: I think there's already an answer by Bruno Le Floch: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15374/4427

Comment: Thank you; didn't use the right keywords.  Will close my own question.