# Align left for left text; align right for middle and right text

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
{\bf Carnegie Mellon University} \hfill {LTI, School of Computer Science} \hfill {\em July 2008 - Present}
{\bf Tsinghua University} \hfill {School of Software} \hfill {\em July 2008 - Present}
```

The code above gives this result:
[image]

How do I make the middle text align to right?

------ Edit ------

What if I have the case that there is some content between these two lines, and I still want the middle text for these two lines to align right? For example:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\bf` etc. are obsolete for quite a time now. Use the LaTeX2e commands instead (`\bfseries` etc.).

Comment: ...see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf` , `\it` , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from answers here I think the most flexible way to achieve what you want is to use `\minipage` environment and apply `\flushright` to the text.

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage{minipage}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
\textbf{Carnegie Mellon University}

\textbf{Tsinghua University}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
LTI, School of Computer Science

School of Software
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
July 2008 -- Present

July 2008 -- Present
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image: aligned text]

Answer (score 1):

A good option is to use a tabular:

Try this in your document

```
\begin{tabular}{l r r}
\textbf{ Carnegie Mellon University} & {LTI, School of Computer Science} &\textit{ July 2008 - Present}\\
\textbf{ Tsinghua University} &{School of Software} & \textit{ July 2008 - Present}\\
\end{tabular}
```

Here is an update using tabularx

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}%

\begin{document}

\noindent
{\bf Carnegie Mellon University} \hfill {LTI, School of Computer Science} \hfill {\em July 2008 - Present}\\
{\bf Tsinghua University} \hfill {School of Software} \hfill {\em July 2008 - Present}\vspace*{20pt}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{L R R}
\textbf{ \mbox{Carnegie Mellon University}} & {\mbox{LTI, School of Computer Science}} &\textit{ July 2008 - Present}\\
\textbf{ Tsinghua University} &{School of Software} & \textit{ July 2008 - Present}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Edit to include text between first and last alligned rows:
Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}%

\begin{document}

Your old code:

\noindent
{\bf Carnegie Mellon University} \hfill {LTI, School of Computer Science} \hfill {\em July 2008 - Present}\\
{\bf Tsinghua University} \hfill {School of Software} \hfill {\em July 2008 - Present}\vspace*{20pt}

My updated code

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{L R R}
\textbf{ \mbox{Carnegie Mellon University}} & {\mbox{LTI, School of Computer Science}} &\textit{ July 2008 - Present}\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{\linewidth}}{Here you can have any possible content that can break in several lines without
causes any problem to the alligned first and last lines\ldots Be carefullldots you need to use p\verb|\linewidth|
to have this kind of line between the others!}\\
\textbf{ Tsinghua University} &{School of Software} & \textit{ July 2008 - Present}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Result:[image]

Update with minipage and itemize:

```
My updated code:\vspace*{10pt}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{L R R}
\textbf{ \mbox{Carnegie Mellon University}} & {\mbox{LTI, School of Computer Science}} &\textit{ July 2008 - Present}\\
\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{\linewidth}}{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Test item one
  \item Test second longer item
  \item These items have nothing to do with the rest alligned tabular...
 \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}\\
\\
\textbf{ Tsinghua University} &{School of Software} & \textit{ July 2008 - Present}\\
\end{tabularx}
```

Last result:
[image]

Comment: Please replace those obsolete macros with the LaTeX2e version.

Comment: Thanks! What about the case that I have some content between these two lines? See the edit of my question.

Comment: @Fei I am not sure if you mean what I done... but this is just an option... if you mean someting else just make it more clear... I am updating again with a minipage inside

Comment: @koleygr Thank you and this is what I am looking for! Sorry that I don't have enough reputation to give you up-vote...

Comment: @Fei... I think you can just select the answer as preffered or correct...

Comment: @koleygr Later I found another answer is more suitable in my case, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem @Fei... but you edited again your answer and my last edit is now out of your subject... You could not do what I did in the last photo with your selected way... Any way... happy you solve it and hope you learn some things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tabular*` and also `array` so you set the formatting in a “centralized” way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  >{\bfseries}l
  r
  >{\itshape}r
  @{}
}
Carnegie Mellon University & LTI, School of Computer Science & July 2008 -- Present \\
Tsinghua University        & School of Software              & July 2008 -- Present
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `geometry` because the standard `article` text width is too small for this table.