# Small caps and underline create inconsistent underlining

Tags: small-caps, underline

I'm attempting to underline section headings in a document, and the behavior of particular letters (like "Q" and "q") as small caps makes the underlining match with the bottom of the lowest part of a letter (the tail in the Q) instead of the base of the letter.  This creates an inconsistent look:

[image]

Here's a minimal example:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \begin{document}
    The problem with ``Q'' is:

    \underline{{\sc This is small caps text.}} \underline{{\sc This is quite weird underlining.}} \underline{{\sc Quite weird.}}

    {\sc \underline{What if we change the order of operations, eh Q?}}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and
[Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Comment: Try with `\underline{\scshape \smash{Q} ...}`.

Comment: The answer depends on whether you want the underline always at a level that will clear descenders, or if it's okay to have it pass through the tail of the Q.  The question cited by @user202729 answers for the lower position.

Comment: I just voted to reopen.  Although the alleged duplicate is closely related, it covers only one approach, and the answer here is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any letter with a descender pushes the underline lower. You can get rid of this descender by using `\smash` (similar to `\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

The problem with ``Q'' is:

\scshape
\underline{This is small caps text.}

\underline{This is \smash{q}uite weird underlining.}

\underline{\smash{Q}uite weird.}

\underline{What if we change the order of operations\smash{,} eh \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{Q}?}

\end{document}
```

Other packages may provide more consistency:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

The problem with ``Q'' is:

\scshape
\uline{This is small caps text.}

\uline{This is quite weird underlining.}

\uline{Quite weird.}

\uline{What if we change the order of operations, eh Q?}

\end{document}
```

Similar output is obtained with a more uniform, lower underline under [`ulem`](//ctan.org/pkg/ulem) and [`soul`](//ctan.org/pkg/soul)'s `\ul` without having to resort to `\smash`ing. Moreover, they allow for underlining with line-breaking.

Comment: Thanks! This is great news -- smash seemed a bit overkill in macros.  Will definitely \ul from now on (and \scshape).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Werner for the answer -- I was using the antiquated two letter command "\sc" instead of the more robust "\scshape" which allows for the "\smash" command:

```
    \underline{\scshape Homework, \smash{Q}uizzes, ...}
```