# Help in Tree diagram using Tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree

My requirement is as follow:

[image]

I've achieved this by using the below tag:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{linguex}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta}%
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}%

\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\ex.
\a. John destroyed the sandcastle.
\b.
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.91\textwidth}
\Tree [.InitP [.{\sc initiator} { John} ] [ [.Init ] [.ProcP
[.{\sc undergoer} { the sandcastle} ] [ [.Proc ] [.ResP [.{\sc
resultee} { $<$the sandcastle$>$ } ] [ [.Res ] [.XP \edge[roof];
{\sc ground$/$final state} ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{adjustbox}


\end{document}
```

And the output comes as:

[image]

How I achieve the left hand marking part, please advise..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy to do by creating named nodes for the relevant heads of your phrases and then using the `positioning` library to add a node to the left.  I've used arrows to connect the nodes; if you just want a line with no arrowhead, remove the `->` from the `\draw` commands.  If you have a lot of these trees, you may find it easier to do this using the `forest` package instead of `tikz-qtree`, since it allows you to instantly create a named node simply by adding a `name=...` key.

I've added both solutions into one document. I've also replaced the `times` package with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`; The `times` package is deprecated. I've also changed all your `\sc` to `\scshape` since two letter font changing commands are also deprecated (see [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/2693) for why). I've created a macro for bar levels, `\1` this is defined already within a `\Tree` environment if you load the `tikz-qtree-compat` package, but is useful to have more generally for syntax.

I've also made a few other cosmetic changes to your tree (and since the tree you've drawn doesn't include Tense, I've left it off of the label.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext} % don't use {times} it's deprecated
\usepackage{linguex}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}%
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\newcommand*\1{\ensuremath{'}}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\ex.
\a. John destroyed the sandcastle.
\b.
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.91\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\Tree [.InitP [.{{\scshape initiator}\\John} ] [.Init\1 [.\node(Init){Init}; ] [.ProcP
[.{{\scshape undergoer}\\the sandcastle} ] [.Proc\1 [.\node(Proc){Proc}; ] [.ResP [.{{\scshape
resultee}\\$<$the sandcastle$>$ } ] [.Res\1 [.\node(Res){Res}; ] [.XP \edge[roof];
{\scshape ground$/$final state} ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\node [below left=3cm of Init,font=\itshape] (D) {destroy};
\draw[->] (D.east) -- (Init);
\draw[->] (D.east) -- (Proc);
\draw[->] (D.east) -- (Res);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\b.
\begin{forest}
[InitP [{{\scshape initiator}\\John} ] [Init\1 [Init,name=Init  ] [ProcP
[{{\scshape undergoer}\\the sandcastle} ] [Proc\1 [Proc,name=Proc  ] [ResP [{{\scshape
resultee}\\$<$the sandcastle$>$ } ] [Res\1 [Res,name=Res  ] [XP[{\scshape ground$/$final state},roof ] ] ] ] ] ]]]
\node [below left=3.5cm of Init,font=\itshape] (D) {destroy};
\draw[->] (D.east) -- (Init);
\draw[->] (D.east) -- (Proc);
\draw[->] (D.east) -- (Res);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: By using this suggestion, vertical bar between the text "initiator" and "John" was missed, please suggest...

Comment: @MadyYuvi That was deliberate on my part. But if you want to put it back, then instead of the node `[{{\scshape Initiator}\\John} ]` use `[{\scshape Initiator} [ John ]]`.  But this is not really appropriate, since *John* isn't a terminal node in the tree. So if you really must show structure there, I would use `[{\scshape Initiator} [ John,roof ]]` (this is using `forest` syntax). The `tikz-qtree` version would be `[.InitP [.{\scshape initiator}   \edge[roof]; John ]`

Comment: is it possible to fix the Tree within text width without using the tag "\begin{adjustbox}...\end{adjustbox}, hence this will reduce the font size by auto....

Comment: @MadyYuvi There are limited things you can do in `tikz-qtree`.  You can make a negative sibling distance: `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,sibling distance=-15pt] ...` will reduce the branch widths substantially in this example without sacrificing readability. You can also add a negative `xshift` to the picture to shift the tree leftwards a bit.   Forest trees are optimized for compactness, (as you can see) so there's less you can do to make them more compact.