# Formating a table using the 'booktabs' package

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have the following script that generates a table that I am trying to format properly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]

\begin{tabular}{c@{\qquad}cccc@{\qquad}ccc@{\qquad}ccc@{\qquad}c}
  \toprule
  \multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-\heavyrulewidth}{Scenarios}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}  {GAM} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SCAM} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Krig} \\
  \cmidrule{2-10}
  & {\tt tp} & {\tt cr} & {\tt ps} & {\tt ad} & {\tt mpi} & {\tt cv} & {\tt   micv} & {\tt mat} & {\tt sph} & {\tt exp}\\
  \midrule
  Uniform & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  1 dominant & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The headers "GAM", "SCAM" and "Krig" are slightly off-centre (pushed to the right). How can this be fixed?

Also, I need the horizontal line below the "Krig" header to extend further to the right. I tried increasing the `10` to `15` in `\cmidrule`, but received an error.

Does someone know how this can be fixed? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, read [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf` , `\it` , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than changing the intercolumn space for some columns, add some empty columns. Also, to fine-tune the vertical placement of the multirowcell, use the optional argument of `\multirow` rather than `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array, multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad}*{14}{c}}
  \toprule
  \multirow{2}{*}[-\heavyrulewidth]{Scenarios}} & \multicolumn{4}{c} {GAM} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SCAM} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Krig} \\
 \cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){7-9} \cmidrule(lr){11-13}
  & {\tt tp} & {\tt cr} & {\tt ps} & {\tt ad} & & {\tt mpi} & {\tt cv} & {\tt micv} & & {\tt mat} & {\tt sph} & {\tt exp}\\
  \midrule
  Uniform & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & & 2 & 3 \\
  1 dominant & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & & 2 & 3 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the optional spacing (contraction) arguments of `\cmidrule`; `\cmidrule(<side>){<cols>}` contracts a rule spanning `<cols>` at the `<sides>`, where `<sides>` identify the `l`eft or `r`ight of the rule. This aids in breaking sub-headings from the rest of the table horizontally.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l *{4}{c} *{3}{c} *{3}{c} }
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{GAM} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SCAM} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Krig} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-5} % GAM
  \cmidrule(lr){6-8} % SCAM
  \cmidrule(lr){9-11} % Krig
  Scenarios & 
    \texttt{tp} & \texttt{cr} & \texttt{ps} & \texttt{ad} & % GAM
    \texttt{mpi} & \texttt{cv} & \texttt{micv} & % SCAM
    \texttt{mat} & \texttt{sph} & \texttt{exp} \\ % Krig
  \midrule
  Uniform    & 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & % GAM
    5 & 6 & 7 & % SCAM
    8 & 9 & 10 \\ % Krig
  1 dominant & 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & % GAM
    5 & 6 & 7 & % SCAM
    8 & 9 & 10 \\ % Krig
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```