# Fontspec changes the bold math

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I wish the `A`, `B` and `C` of the matrices defined as follow were written using the default computer modern font. I'm using the `fontspec` package with `LuaLaTeX`, but when I set the main font it also changes the math bold font. Here's an excerpt of my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \disablehyphenation

\usepackage[
    hmarginratio = 1:1,
    left = 3cm,
    right = 2cm,
    top = 3cm,
    bottom = 2cm
    ]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Arno Pro}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
    $ {\bf A}_{2\times 3}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6
    \end{pmatrix}
    %
    \hspace{.5cm}
    %
    {\bf B}_{4\times 3}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    1 & 2 & 3
    \end{bmatrix}
    %
    \hspace{.5cm}
    %
    {\bf C}_{2\times 2}=\begin{Vmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4
    \end{Vmatrix} $
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Bold Math font changes as well]

As you can see the bold math font is not the computer modern but the numbers are. Although both of them are inside the math environment.

Comment: Don't use `\bf`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/35864. `\mathbf` seems more appropriate here. But I'm not sure if this solves your problem. But even if not, you should definitely not be using `\bf` any more anywhere.

Comment: Use \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} if you don't want fontspec to interfere.

Comment: I tried it, but i get the following error:
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package fontspec.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
                                                  
l.16     \setmainfont
                   {Arno Pro}
The package fontspec has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [no-math]
Adding the global options:
  ,no-math
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.

Comment: `@moewe` I changed to `\textbf{}` and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Mhh, I suggested `\mathbf` and not `\textbf`. And that is what I would use. But I don't know if this will solve the actual issue at hand. Still you should not be using `\bf`.

Comment: Re the option clash: Load `fontspec` before `polyglossia`.

Comment: `@moewe` I'm sorry. I meant `\mathbf` not `\textbf`. Also, I loaded `fontspec` before `polyglossia`, but the issue continues.

Comment: In the MWE things work for me (with `Linux Libertine` instead of `Arno Pro`, but that should be irrelevant) if I load `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` before `polyglossia` and use `\mathbf`.

Comment: Okay! Now I got it correctly. I loaded `fontspec` before `polyglossia` and added the option `[no-math]`. Thanks to `@moewe` and `@Ulrike Fischer` answers combined it's all nice and tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

With the help of the members `@moewe` and `@Ulrike Fischer` in the comments I loaded the `fontspec` package before the `polyglossia` with the option `[no-math]`and also changed the `{\bf }` to `\mathbf{}`.