# fontspec no-math option changes the math bold alphabet

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, mtpro, math-fonts

I have a setup that works well with `pdflatex` and that I would like to carry it over to `xelatex` or `lualatex`, but `fontspec` seems to be changing the math-bold alphabet -- even if called with the [no-math] option. Consider the file:

```
% To be run with pdflatex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
$abcdefg....$

$\mathbf{abcdefg...}$

$\mbf{abcdefg...}$
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Now moving over to `xelatex` the equivalent should be:

```
% To be run with xe-lua-latex    
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
$abcdefg...$

$\mathbf{abcdefg...}$

$\mbf{abcdefg...}$
\end{document}
```

The option [no-math] here is required to keep `fontspec` from using CM fonts inside math-mode...but then if one use it, the results are:

[image]

that is, the \mathbold alphabet is changed - the mid-line uses a different weight.

I am well aware of the question [Fontspec changes the bold math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434317/fontspec-changes-the-bold-math) and tried everything there and it does not seem to apply.

Comment: mtpro2 defines \mathbf etc by using `\encodingdefault`  and `\rmdefault`. As `\encodingdefault`  is TU with the unicode engines and `\rmdefault` is different too this gives quite different fonts.

Comment: @Ulrike, can this be fixed by mimicking what has been done for \mbf -- which seems to work fine in xe-lua-latex?

Comment: Sure, you can always redefine \mathbf to whatever you want.

Comment: I am looking at the code, all written by Walter A. Schmidt, who I believe has a lot of experience writing code for font usage in TeX. It seems that he specified all math-alphabets in a very portable way that carried nicely into XeTeX and LuaTeX, but NOT this particular one -- \mathbf. I was wondering if there are any reasons for that.

Comment: All mathalphabets in mt2pro are defined so that they follow the text font. If you switch to times or palatino in pdftex, mathbf will be using times or palatino too (correct loading order assumed). The same happens with luatex, so behaviour is quite consistent. The only problem is that mt2pro uses `b` instead of `bx` as series.

Comment: @Ulrike, And how come that works in pdflatex?

Comment: What works in pdflatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Could you please explain, why is a problem that `mt2pro` uses `b` instead of `bx`?

Comment: @TeXtnik see the luatex example, the mathbf is not bold as fontspec sets up only the bx series, and so you get in the log `Font shape 'TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/b/n' undefined using 'TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n'` which means that latex falls back to the m series.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, explaining my comment 3 lines above: Everything works fine in `pdflatex`, with \mathbf you get a lite-bold and with \mbf you get heavy-bold; but in `xelatex` only \mbf works and one of the fonts is not found. I gather the difference is in the definition of the alphabets `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}` versus 
`\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mbf}{U}{mtt}{b}{n}`. What I do not understand is WHY these definitions are so different. Are there are requirements driving it?

Comment: \mbf always uses the same (mtpro2 specific) font, \mathbf follows the text font and so depends on it. It is a decision of the package author (which didn't know about unicode engines when writing it) to setup things like that, and if you don't like it,  change it.

Answer (score 7):

You have made some misunderstood claims here: 1) `\mathbf` does **not** give you lite-bold; 2) `\mbf` does **not** give you heavy-bold. I’d like to first correct some misconceptions and then present a solution.

In your examples you are using the `\mathbf` alphabet, not the `\mathbold` alphabet. In fact, `mtpro2` declares the latter by

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbold}{LMP1}{mtt}{b}{it}
```

which means that the `\mathbold` alphabet is **b**old and **it**alic. You must purchase the complete version of `mtpro2` to get this alphabet. So your `lite` examples have nothing to do with `\mathbold`. The `\mbf` alphabet, however, does exist with the lite version, and `\mbf` is indeed a separately designed **bold upright math font**. All heavy math fonts are available only with the complete version.

Under the NFSS (New Font Selection Scheme) of LaTeX2e, the commands `\mathrm`, `\mathbf`, `\mathit`, `\mathsf`, `\mathtt`, etc., switch to **text fonts** in **math mode**. So when you type

```
$\mathbf{a-b}$
```

The `a` and the `b` will be printed in bold upright face of the **text font**, while the hyphen `-` behaves like the minus sign because you are in **math mode**. The `\mathXX` commands only affect what’s called the `\mathalpha` class (usually includes all digits, lower and upper Latin letters).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% `no-math' is no longer needed since v2.7b (2019/02/12)
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}% For illustration purpose
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$012abcdefg$, `no-math' is no longer needed, digits stay as MathT\i me\par
$\mathbf{012abcdefg}$, text font in math mode\par
$\mbf{012abcdefg}$, real bold upright math alphabet
\end{document}
```

> [image: comic sans]
>   See? The `\mathbf` command switches to text font (Comic Sans MS) here.

If you look closely in your pdfLaTeX example, then you should realize that `\mathbf` switches to **Computer Modern Bold**, which seems to be “semi-bold” because the default is **Computer Modern Bold Extended**. Maybe this is why you think `\mbf` is heavy: It isn’t.

---

## Solution

You have *Times New Roman* for Windows, *Times* for MacOS, *Nimbus Roman No. 9 L* for Linux. These are all Times-like digitization of the same/similar metal types. In the TeX world, you have *TeX Gyre Termes*. For cross-platform considerations, I would suggests TeX Gyre Termes (IMHO, it has better support in, of course, TeX).

Unfortunately `mtpro2` uses *fixed* font attributes. This is because the legacy Times family, called `ptm`, has bold face in the `b` series. Let’s help `mtpro2` to re-declare related commands by using *implicit* font attributes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% `no-math' is no longer needed since v2.7b (2019/02/12)
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}% For the TeX world, truly cross-platform
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{\mddefault}{\updefault}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{\bfdefault}{\updefault}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{\bfdefault}{\updefault}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{\mddefault}{\itdefault}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{\mddefault}{\updefault}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{\mddefault}{\updefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{\bfdefault}{\itdefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\updefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{\bfdefault}{\updefault}

\newcommand*\test[1]{\texttt{\string#1}: $#1{012abc}$}

\begin{document}
Normal math: $012abc$\par
\test\mbf\par
\test\mathrm, $\sin$\par
\test\mathbf\par
\test\mathit\par
\test\mathsf\par
\test\mathtt

Switch to \verb|\boldmath| now:\par
\boldmath
\test\mathrm, $\sin$\par
\test\mathbf\par
\test\mathit\par
\test\mathsf\par
\test\mathtt
\end{document}
```

> [image: bold alphabet]

---

P.S. The `no-math` option is no longer needed since `fontspec` v2.7b (2019/02/12). See [this CTAN announcement](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2171.1550068180.5014.ctan-ann@ctan.org).

Comment: An issue has been opened to `fontspec` at https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/360

Comment: A perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

The `fontspec` package allows you to set the math font with `\setmathrm`, and the `\mathbf` font with the `BoldFont =` option of `\setmathrm`. (**ETA:** *Thanks to Ruixi Zhang.*  As of March 2019, this is bugged if you select `[no-math]`.)

The example in the manual for loading a bold NFSS font as `\mathbf` is:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbf{U}{eur}{b}{n}
```

Ruixi Zhang has a great answer that expands on this.

Other options include `mathastext` and, in XeLaTeX, `mathspec`.  You could also drop the legacy 8-bit fonts entirely and use `unicode-math` with something like STIX Two Math.

Comment: Hmm… `\setmathrm{Times New Roman}` no longer works with `mtpro2`, not even `\setmathrm{Times New Roman}[BoldFont = Times New Roman Bold]`. As I noted in my answer, since v2.7b, `fontspec` will automatically execute `no-math` when `mtpro2` is detected. However, `\setmathrm` works only if `no-math` is NOT executed. So your solution is no longer valid under this new feature of `fontspec`.

Comment: @ruixi It sounds like a bug if \setmathrm is affected by [no-math]...

Comment: @WillRobertson Interestingly, if I adjusted the `\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}...` code block, I got this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k4HF.png

Comment: @RuixiZhang I’m not completely sure what MCVE is producing those results, but I’ll note that `\boldmath\mathbf` in `fontspec` would be set with the command `\setboldmathrm{...}[ BoldFont = ... ]`.  I’m sure you knew that already, but I mention it because you point out it wasn’t doing anything by default (possibly because the default font family doesn’t come in extra-bold).

Comment: @Davislor Apologies. The picture in my previous comment was meant to point out missing code in `fontspec`. See, with standard LaTeX2e, `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} $abc\mathbf{abc}$ \boldmath$abc\mathbf{abc}$ \end{document}` shows that `\mathbf` stays the same. If I then add `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmathrm{TeX Gyre Termes}` to the preamble, then the first `\mathbf` is in TeX Gyre Termes Bold, while the second is (still) in Computer Modern Bold Extended. One would expect, without the presence of “Extra Bold”, the two `\mathbf` to be the same.