# Two different citation methods

Tags: bibtex, citing

Can anyone tell me the basic difference
between

```
\rm \cite{}
```

and

```
\cite{}
```

while citing a manuscript. After compiling I could not find the differences, but there must be some. Kindly help. Thanks a lot for your attention and help.

Comment: `\rm \cite{}` is quite likely wrong, but `\cite{}` is fine. `\rm` is a font 'switch' that has been deprecated for about 25 years now. It should not be used: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/35864. Presumably the author added it to obtain an upright/Roman citation in an otherwise italic or bold context. If `\cite` looks alright where you use it, do not add `\rm`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot. Yeah \cite{} is working fine.

Comment: And even if `\cite` does not look right, don't add `\rm`. You can use a modern NFSS switch or macro in that case, see https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2letterfontcmd.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments