# Unable to use \texit in \caption

Tags: captions, templates, italic

I am trying to italicize species names in a caption:

```
\caption{The results of recoding \textit{A. victoria} towards the $2$-mer frequency distribution of the highly expressed genes of \textit{E. coli}. This visualization was generated with the command \texttt{freqgen visualize -{}-original gfp.fna -{}-target ecoli.heg.yaml -{}-optimized gfp\_ecoli.fna -{}-title "Recoding GFP using Freqgen"}.}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work:

[image: example]

`\texttt` is clearly working, so why isn't `\textit`?

If it is of any help, I am using `bioinfo.cls` for the journal [Bioinformatics](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/pages/submission_online).

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please, always provide small complete document (called mwe: minimal working example) which demonstrate your problem. without it is almost impossible to say, what is going wrong with your caption.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is due to a typo in `bioinfo.cls` which has

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phb}
```

which points to a non existent `phb` family, instead of the correct

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
```

You solve the issue by doing

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % fix the error in the class

<everything that follows>
```

With the change applied to the sample file and the caption copied from your question, I get the expected result (with the caption in sans serif type).

[image]

---

Actually, the family `phb` is defined in Karl Berry’s scheme, but it points to the Hobo font, which is quite unlikely used by a scientific journal for its captions. This is the reason why I suspect that `bioinfo.cls` has just a typo, because `phv` points instead to the commonly used Helvetica font.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing `\textit{A. victoria}` to `{\it A. victoria}`.

Comment: Just to mention that normally, the two-letter font commands should not be used any more: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/35864. But it may well be that the class is using extremely old code or follows bad practices.