# How to reduce the white space between top of the page and headrule ONLY on pages other than the first?

Tags: spacing

See the figure below:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=6mm,includehead,headheight=60pt, left=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,right=1.5cm,headsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.2pt}% linha no header 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.2pt} % linha no footer

\setlength{\headsep}{\dimexpr\headsep+1.2\baselineskip+.4pt}

\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{
  \if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
  \vskip10pt% change here
  \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth   
  \vskip-\headrulewidth%
}}
\makeatother


 \lfoot{\tt \today}
 \rfoot{\tt 14 de dezembro de 2018}


\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
\lhead{
\def\sc{0.6}
\def\rc{\sc*0.1cm} % rc = 10% de sc
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\sc]
\definecolor{tempcolor}{RGB}{200,25,30}
\filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\rc] (2cm,0cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-0.5cm);
\filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\rc] (2cm,-0.6cm) rectangle (1.1cm,-1.1cm);
\filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\rc] (2cm,-0.6cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-1.1cm);
\filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\rc] (1.7cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-1.7cm);
\filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\rc] (0.6cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.1cm,-1.7cm);
\filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\rc] (1.6cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.8cm,-1.7cm);
\filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\rc] (1.7cm,-1.8cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-2.3cm);
\node[scale=\sc,fill=white] at (5.92,-0.85) {\resizebox{6.7cm}{0.5cm}{\sf \textbf{ESCOLA}}};
\node[scale=\sc,fill=white] at (4.52,-1.55) {\resizebox{5cm}{0.5cm}{\sf {Construindo o Futuro}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}     
\rhead{\tikz \node at (0,0) { \textbf{Prova de Física}};\\ 
\tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=8.5cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\tt Aluno(a)}:}] { \phantom{\tt 15,0} };}   
\tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\tt Turma}:}] {\phantom{\tt 15,0}};}   
\tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\tt Valor}:}] { \tt 15,0};} 
\tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\tt Nota}:}] {\phantom{\tt 15,0}};}
}
 \lfoot{\tt Prof. Lucas}
 \rfoot{\tt \today}
}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\begin{multicols}{2} 

\lipsum[3-20]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I see you're using `\sc` (for *scale*) and `\tt`, `\sf` for font... Please see [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it` , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764) and [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the page layout to match the bulk of your document. That is, for pages two onward. Then set the first page header with some added `\vspace` at the beginning, before your `multicols`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=6mm,includehead,left=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,right=1.5cm,headsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.2pt} % linha no footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.2pt}% linha no header 

\lfoot{\ttfamily \today}
\rfoot{\ttfamily 14 de dezembro de 2018}

\pagestyle{fancy} 

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \lhead{%
    \def\scale{0.6}%
    \def\roundc{\scale*0.1cm}% rc = 10% de sc
    \raisebox{-2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\scale]
      \definecolor{tempcolor}{RGB}{200,25,30}
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (2cm,0cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-0.5cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (2cm,-0.6cm) rectangle (1.1cm,-1.1cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (2cm,-0.6cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-1.1cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (1.7cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (0.6cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.1cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (1.6cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.8cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (1.7cm,-1.8cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-2.3cm);
      \node[scale=\scale,fill=white] at (5.92,-0.85) {\resizebox{6.7cm}{0.5cm}{\sffamily \textbf{ESCOLA}}};
      \node[scale=\scale,fill=white] at (4.52,-1.55) {\resizebox{5cm}{0.5cm}{\sffamily {Construindo o Futuro}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
  }
  \chead{\raisebox{-2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\rule[-2.5\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1.2pt}}}
  \rhead{\raisebox{-2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
    \tikz \node at (0,0) {\textbf{Prova de Física}};\\ 
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=8.5cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Aluno(a)}:}] {\phantom{\ttfamily 15,0}};}   
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Turma}:}] {\phantom{\ttfamily 15,0}};}   
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Valor}:}] {\ttfamily 15,0};} 
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Nota}:}] {\phantom{\ttfamily 15,0}};}
    \end{tabular}}
  }
  \lfoot{\ttfamily Prof. Lucas}
  \rfoot{\ttfamily \today}
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \thispagestyle{firststyle}
  \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2} 

\sloppy\lipsum[3-30]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

To avoid issues with the header for the first page not matching that of the rest of the document, set the `\smash` the content (and/or move it into position with `\raisebox{<len>}[0pt][0pt]`).