# How to make a line in header and footer in the first page?

Tags: header-footer

I am writing a proposal, and trying to decorate my header and footer by a line. The problem that I face with is the line under footer and header only appear on from the second page to the end, while there is no line in the first page. Here is the code that I used:

```
\documentclass{arp}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{parskip}
\parskip=3pt

\usepackage{fancyhdr}     
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\bf{XXXXXXXX}}
\lhead{\bf{YYYYYYYYYYYY}}
\lfoot{\bf{ZZZZZZZZZ}}
\rfoot{\bf{\thepage}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please extend your code to a [complete but minimal document](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces the problem you encounter.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the `arp.cls`. Assuming your first page uses page style `plain` you have to redefine `\plainheadrulewidth` and `plainfootrulewidth`, too.

```
\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\plainfootrulewidth}{0.5pt}
```

If the width of the rules should be the same on both `plain` and `fancy` pages, you can use

```
\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\plainfootrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{\plainheadrulewidth}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\plainfootrulewidth}
```

Example using the `report` class:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\textbf{XXXXXXXX}}
\lhead{\textbf{YYYYYYYYYYYY}}
\lfoot{\textbf{ZZZZZZZZZ}}
\rfoot{\textbf{\thepage}}

\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\plainfootrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{\plainheadrulewidth}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\plainfootrulewidth}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't this make a header that is the same on all pages? I think maybe what the OP meant was different text in the header for page 1 than the rest of the document?

Comment: The header text already was the same on all pages. The OP only misses the header and footer line on the first page.  Now the header and footer are the same on all pages (= desired result).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this `arp` document class, but using `article` instead, you could modify the `plain` style and it would work as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{parskip}
\parskip=3pt

\usepackage{fancyhdr}     
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\rhead{\bf{XXXXXXXX}}
\lhead{\bf{YYYYYYYYYYYY}}
\lfoot{\bf{ZZZZZZZZZ}}
\rfoot{\bf{\thepage}}
}

\author{Me}
\title{A Nice Title}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \clearpage

    Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and/or [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Comment: I just modified the original example, but useful links. Thanks :-)

Comment: You should consider going the extra step and address any other shortcomings rather than just the requested help. That should be easy to do in this case.