# installing linguex into a main tex thesis file

Tags: errors, linguistics, thesis, linguex

The latex file has problems installing/using the linguex package in a ucla thesis latex template (uclathes) (downloaded from GitHub). I inserted it in a preamble of the mother tex file, but it keeps sending `undefined sequence' errors every time I use it to gloss linguistic examples in the \exig. environment and I don't know how to fix it so that the error stops occurring. What is confusing is that all the examples in \exig. are perfectly printed out when compiled in the pdf despite the fact that they appear labeled as errors in tex document. Here is the (near minimal) code of the main tex file.

```
\documentclass [PhD] {uclathes}
\usepackage{linguex}


\begin {document}


\chapter{Introduction}

\exig. Vazan je zadatak.\\
important be{\sc.prs.3sg} task\\
`A task is important.'


\end {document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome to Tex SX! Could you make your example fully compiliable by any user, deleting or commenting out `\input` and `\bibliography` lines, and giving just one simple example with the `exig` environment? Did you have the same troubles with a standard `article` document class? If so, you can change the document class and it will be easier to help.

Comment: No, there are no problems with \exig and linguex in  the article document. If I changed the document class, wouldn't I lose all the uclathesis dissertation formatting that comes with the package or is that a separate issue?

Comment: For future questions, it would be helpful to provide a link to the document class (rather than just mentioning github) and providing the explicit error your received (which would have told you that `\sc` was the undefined control sequence.)

Answer (score 3):

Two letter font commands such as `\sc`, `\it`, `\bf` are deprecated. This is the source of your error. The `uclathes` class properly doesn't define them since they are so old and not supposed to be used in LaTeX. It has nothing to do with the `linguex` package. Replace `\sc` with `\scshape`, `\it` with `\itshape` and `\bf` with `\bfseries` etc. and your file compiles fine.  See [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/2693) for more details.

Unfortunately the `linguex` package also uses these two letter font commands in one of its built-in macros `\exi`. To solve that problem, you will need to supply definitions of the two letter commands yourself.  You can do this by adding

```
\let\rm\rmfamily

\documentclass [PhD] {uclathes}
\usepackage{linguex}
\let\rm\rmfamily

\begin {document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\exig. Vazan je zadatak.\\
important be{\scshape.prs.3sg} task\\
`A task is important.'

\exi. [BeP interesting [Be ] [PredP this book interesting]]

\end {document}
```

But instead of putting formatting like this for your feature annotations, it would be better to create a macro:

```
\documentclass [PhD] {uclathes}
\usepackage{linguex}
\let\rm\rmfamily
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\feat}{\scshape}

\begin {document}


\chapter{Introduction}

\exig. Vazan je zadatak.\\
important be\feat{.prs.3sg} task\\
`A task is important.'

\exi. [BeP interesting [Be ] [PredP this book interesting]]

\end {document}
```

[image: output of code]