# linguex in uclathes

Tags: errors, linguistics, linguex

\exi. environment sends `undefined sequence' error. How can I fix it?
 Here is the code of the main tex file.

```
\documentclass [PhD] {uclathes}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{linguex}


\begin {document}


\chapter{Introduction}

\exi. [BeP interesting [Be ] [PredP this book \sout{interesting}]]

\end {document}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the `uclathes` class?

Answer (score 1):

The `linguex` package unfortunately still uses the old two letter font commands, and these would need to be defined by the class.  The `uclathes` class correctly doesn't define them, (see [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/2693) for reasons why) so you need to provide them yourself.

```
\documentclass [PhD] {uclathes}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{linguex}
\let\rm\rmfamily


\begin {document}


\chapter{Introduction}

\exi. [BeP interesting [Be ] [PredP this book \sout{interesting}]]

\end {document}
```

[image: output of code]