# How can I define font size and style for ExPex text?

Tags: linguistics, expex

disclaimer: I am very new for LaTeX, so please do not redirect me to documentation, I read carefully several times ExPex PDF guide (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/generic/expex/expex-doc.pdf) and was unable to achieve what I needed.

Below is sample text which uses ExPex module:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{expex} 
\title{Glossary}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\ex[glstyle=nlevel,glneveryline={\bf,\it},glwordalign=center,exnoformat=X,exno=,glspace=1em,glwidth=5in,
,extraglskip=8pt]

\begingl
Abc[Abc]
def[def]
hij.[hij.]
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

Which renders to this representation:

[image: ExPex render]

The maximun I was able to change font style: bold or italic, but not font size. But I need to contol font size. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose the font commands in braces. But don't use the two letter font commands; they are deprecated in LaTeX. (See [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/2693)).  Because the ExPex author is a plain TeX user, the documentation uses the two letter commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{expex} 
\title{Glossary}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\ex[glstyle=nlevel,glneveryline={{\bfseries\Large},{\itshape\Huge}},glwordalign=center,exnoformat=X,exno=,glspace=1em,glwidth=5in,
,extraglskip=8pt]

\begingl
Abc[Abc]
def[def]
hij.[hij.]
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Perfect! You're my life saver! I tried to achieve this for several weeks...