# Edit style for italic caption

Tags: captions

I have a style for Fig caption like below.

```
\def\fnum@figure{\small\it\bf\figurename{} \thefigure.}
```

This style change the caption and caption number bold. 
But I need bold and italic numbering and only italic for caption like below.

***Fig 1.3:*** *This is my caption*

Any solution?

I have a style file and this file has a command like below.

```
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
```

So `\captionsetup[figure]{font={it,bf}}` not worked.

In this style file there is a command `\newcommand{\captionfonts}{\normalfont}`

Can I edit this command and how?

@Werner I have tried your solution it works at a new document, but in my exist document its not work :( No any change.

Comment: `\it\bf`? neither `\it` nor `\bf` have been defined by default in latex since 1993, if they are defined for compatibility they do not combine, `\it\bf` is the same as `\bf`, you want `\itshape\bfseries`

Comment: ...see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Comment: Can you supply the `\documentclass` you're using?

Comment: Without knowing more information, it's not possible to help you. Please supply a [minimal document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that replicates your current problem. Can you do that?

Comment: If you have to use a particular style, why are you trying to override it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply load the `caption` package and use

```
\captionsetup[figure]{font=it, labelfont+=bf} ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
\captionsetup[figure]{
  font = it,
  labelfont = bf
}
```

which sets the entire caption `font` in `it`alics, adding `b`old`f`ace only to the `labelfont` (which contains the float type, number and separator).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
  compatibility = false
}

% Set up caption options for figures
\captionsetup[figure]{
  font = it,
  labelfont = bf
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Of course, this only works if you are using a `\documentclass` that is patchable by [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption).