# How would I define a character to start and end an environment in plain TeX?

Tags: environments, catcodes, definition

In `TeX`, starting and ending math mode is done with the same symbol, namely `$`. Suppose I would like to start and end an environment like this, perhaps with the text italic, using the character `*`, as follows. The code `*this is italic*` would typeset *this text is italic*. I have attempted the following solution but it does not work.

```
\catcode`*\active
\def*#1{\bgroup\it#1\egroup}
*this is italic*
\bye
```

I have also tried

```
\catcode`*\active
\newif\ifitalic
\def*#1{\ifitalic\egroup\italicfalse\else\italictrue\bgroup\it#1\fi}
*this is italic*
\bye
```

But they both throw the error

```
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before * was complete.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might have noticed that they are trying to replace `$...$` with `\(...\)`, since keeping track of even-odd occurrences of $ is difficult (some editors change the font color with each occurrence).

Comment: The purpose of this question is to be able to type italics and bold fonts like in markdown  or another? Because in first case, exist the `markdown` package ...

Comment: It woudn’t be the most robust solution, but why not do `\def*#1*{...}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your macro `*` reads only single following token (after ignoring spaces) because you say `\def*#1{...}`, i.e. the `#1` is unseparated parameter. The first usage of `*` gets `t` to the `#1` and the second usage (at the end of the phrase) gets `\par` to the `#1` (if empty line follows) and the result is "paragraph ended before \par" because `*` isn't defined as `\long`. If there is `\bye` without empty line (this is exactly in your example) then `\bye` is scanned to `#1` and the result is "Forbidden control sequence" because `\bye` is defined as `\outer` in plain TeX.

You can define "switching macro" `\startit` without parameter as follows:

```
\def\startit{\bgroup \let\startit=\egroup \it}

\catcode`*=13
\def*{\startit}

Test *this is italic*
\bye
```

The first usage of `*` starts the group, selects italic font and redefines `\startit` to `\egroup`. The second usage of `*` (at the end of the phrase) runs `\startit` in the meaning `\egroup` and closes the group (the italic font is not selected now). Moreover, the `\startit` gets its original meaning after `\egroup`, so next possible `*` opens italic text again.

Egreg showed an example how to combine `*` with italic meaning and `**` with bold meaning. Moreower, `**` in italic does nothing and `*` in bold selects bold italic. The same behavior can be achieved by following seven lines:

```
\font\bi=cmbxti10

\catcode`\*=13
\def*{\activeast}
\def\activeast{\futurelet\next\aastA}
\def\aastA{\ifx*\next \expandafter \startbf \else \startit \fi}
\def\startit{\bgroup \def\startbf*{}\let\startit=\egroup \it}
\def\startbf*{\bgroup \let\it=\bi \def\startbf*{\egroup}\bf}

Hello, *th**i**s* is a **test, *to see* whether** it works.

\bye
```

Note that the code is much more compact than egreg's code at 34 lines.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a “plainification” of Bruno Le Floch's code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15374/4427

```
\font\bfit=cmbxti10

\catcode`@=11

% boilerplate
\long\def\@gobble#1{}
\long\def\@firstofone#1{#1}

\def\star@out{%
  \star@ifnext{\bgroup\bf\let\star@current\star@inbf\@gobble}%
              {\bgroup\it\let\star@current\star@init}%
}
\def\star@inbf{%
  \star@ifnext{\egroup\@gobble}{\bgroup\bfit\let\star@current\star@initbf}%
}
\def\star@init{%
  \star@ifnext{\bgroup\bf\let\star@current\star@initbf}{\egroup}%
}
\def\star@initbf{\star@ifnext{\egroup\@gobble}{\egroup}}
\let\star@current\star@out

\def\star@ifnext#1#2{%
  \def \reserved@a {#1}%
  \def \reserved@b {#2}%
  \futurelet \@let@token \star@ifnext@aux 
}
\begingroup
\catcode`\*=13
\@firstofone{\endgroup
  \def*{\star@current}
  \def\star@ifnext@aux{%
    \ifx \@let@token *\let \reserved@c \reserved@a 
    \else             \let \reserved@c \reserved@b 
    \fi 
    \reserved@c
  }
}
\catcode`@=12

\catcode`\*=\active

Hello, *th**i**s* is a **test, *to see* whether** it works.

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the character `*` as a parameter delimeter.

```
\catcode`\*=\active
    \def*#1*{\bgroup\it#1\egroup}
    *this is italic*, but this isn't
\bye
```

Comment: Your second code doesnt work because the macro tries to use `\bye` as argument, what generate an error. Try to define without the parameter `#1`: `\def*{\ifitalic\egroup\italicfalse\else\italictrue\bgroup\it\fi}`.