# Italicized effects remainder of document \it{} compared to {\it{}}

Tags: errors, italic

Here are the two different code snippets.

The code with `{\it{}}` seems to correctly italicize only the braced text. When I use `\it{}` it italicizes the remainder of the document. Why is that?

`{\it{}}` with code and example

```
\item Determine whether the following is {\it{always true, sometimes true}}, or {\it{never true}}. Explain. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\vec{a}(t)$ is perpendicular to $\vec{N}(t)$.
\item $\vec{a}(t)$ is perpendicular to $\vec{r}(t)$. 
\item $\vec{v}(t)$ is perpendicular to $\vec{r}(t)$. 
\end{enumerate}
```

Outputs
[image]

`\it{}` with code and example...

```
\item Determine whether the following is \it{always true, sometimes true}, or \it{never true}. Explain. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\vec{a}(t)$ is perpendicular to $\vec{N}(t)$.
\item $\vec{a}(t)$ is perpendicular to $\vec{r}(t)$. 
\item $\vec{v}(t)$ is perpendicular to $\vec{r}(t)$. 
\end{enumerate}

my favorite text.
```

Outputs
[image]

Comment: `\it`is not valid LaTeX (since many years, as someone probably will tell you). Use `{\itshape ... }` or `\textit{ ... }`

Comment: \it should not be used at all but if used it makes the following text italic up to the end of the document or current group

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764)
[Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Comment: If you want to emphasize a word like that, use `\emph{word}`

Comment: ah okay. thank you!