# Valid reasons not to use old TeX commands in LaTeX2ε

Tags: pdftex, compiling

Are there reasons not to use the old commands of `TeX`, like `\rm`, `\em`, `\sl`, etc. in `LaTeX`?

Yet they still work when I use them.

Comment: Related question: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/will-two-letter-font-style-commands-bf-it-ever-be-resurrected-in-latex)

Comment: Would you say that not being able to combine `\it` and `\bf` to create ***bold-italic text*** is a valid reason for not using the "old" font commands?

Comment: Not all classes define them. That's reason enough for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default they are not defined.

Some classes define them for compatibility with documents from the 1980s but why would you want that? In other classes you would simply get an undefined command error.

The commands are, in most cases, less intuitive than the standard commands as they do not combine. `\it\bf` is upright bold, not bold italic.

Note this applies to `\rm`, `\sf`, `\bf`, `\it`. Not to `\em` which is a standard latex command.

Comment: I thank you with all my heart.