# column width inside a tabularx multicolumn

Tags: tabularx

I want to use some appropriate parameter inside a multicolumn command in order to draw a horizontal rule of the width of the column.
I tried `\linewidth`without success
In the example below, my objective is to draw a line between points A and D (ideally) or between B and C.
The column separator vertical bars are here only for showing column limits.

Thanks for yor help

Henri

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{15.5cm}{|X|c|X|c|X|c|X|c|X|}
\multicolumn{9}{c}{ {\bf Aaaaa}}
\\
\multicolumn{9}{c}{ \&{} {\bf Bbbbb}}
\\
\multicolumn{9}{c}{\rule{0.5pt}{0.5cm}}
\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{A}&
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{}&
\multicolumn{1}{r}{C}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{D}
\\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\rule{0.60cm}{0.5pt}}&
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\rule{8cm}{0.5pt}}& % this should be \linewidth
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rule{0.60cm}{0.5pt}}
\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rule{0.5pt}{0.5cm}}&&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rule{0.5pt}{0.5cm}}&&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rule{0.5pt}{0.5cm}}&&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rule{0.5pt}{0.5cm}}&&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rule{0.5pt}{0.5cm}}
\\
\begin{center}{\bf Ccccc xx}\end{center} & &
\begin{center}{\bf Ddddd}\end{center} & &
\begin{center}{\bf Eeeee\\wider text ideally without hyphenation}\end{center} & &
\begin{center}{\bf Fffff xx}\end{center} & &
\begin{center}{\bf Ggggg}\end{center}
\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix and add your lines via tikz

Comment: `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex for 30 years. You can fill a multicolumn c column using using `\hrulefill`

Comment: Off-topic: [You should not use old font commands like `\bf` any longer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/277964). And [maybe you should use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}…\end{center}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/277964) (and replace `\\ ` by `\tabularnewline` where needed) or even add `>{\centering}` or `>{\Centering}` (last needs package `ragged2e`) before the `X`.

Comment: For me it seems this should not be a table but a kind of tree. So you should [use TikZ to draw the tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-trees).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will look at nicematrix and TikZ, but my data, which is indeed a tree, is in the form of a table. I assume \hrulefill will extend across the shole column. How about 1/2 column width??