# wider overall kerning for emphasis

Tags: kerning, emphasis

Some older texts use wider kerning to emphasise text (see picture). I would like to mimic that in LaTeX. Is it possible to set up an environment (like \bf or \em) that does this?
[image: excerpt from Lehrbuch der Algebra by Heinrich Weber]

Comment: (and you shouldn't use `\bf`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/will-two-letter-font-style-commands-bf-it-ever-be-resurrected-in-latex )